# Why are users answering questions as quickly as possible?

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

Very often, I read a question and think about an answer. During my thought process I see that new answers pop up very quickly but sometimes they are incomplete or address only part of the question.

Can't Stack Overflow's reward system, or better: the answering workflow be overhauled in order to address that problem? For example introduce a minimum time that has to expire after a question has been asked before an answer can be posted but prepared?

I feel that lots of users simply want to make the quickest answer as possible to claim the reward of an upvote or acceptance.

Often those answers are reviewed and changed during the course of the next minutes which makes them incrementally better. But the initial wave of answers is very often just a first thought that could have been hold back before refinement and personal approval of the author himself.

**Update**

I just want to address some of your answers and comments.

On a second thought my question is still valid but I also see that one aspect of the nature of the Stack Exchange Network is to trade response for some kind of acknowledgement. You are also right in saying that sometimes you need a quick answer and I have to admit that I have already been given very good answers in almost an instant, too. So probably the trade off of getting this incredibly good and fast response rate is to sometimes have quick and dirty answers. It seems very difficult if not impossible to force any kind of quality without losing what makes Stack Overflow so cool. And probably it is not always a bad thing to see a posts' progress during later improvement.

Comment: [MSE: Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: So what is the problem with people answering with an initial draft? If the answer is improved to a decent quality, where is the harm?

Comment: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers)

Comment: @user000001: There isn't any harm, so long as the answer's good.  However, I vote based on a post's state *when I see it,* so if you write a half-assed initial draft, it's going to get my downvote, and I'm not going to remove it later.

Comment: @user000001, its confusing to the asker their question wasn't answered. They may start creating more comments or editing their question in response to a poor drafted answer.  This creates clutter and confusion.  Had the asker known to refresh every minute until the "fastest guns" stopped shooting, then it could relieve some of the confusion.  But I think that is a poor expectation and user experience.  When I ask a question, I expect a well thought out and full response.  I don't expect to have to keep refreshing and asking "why didn't you answer the full question"?

Comment: Think about it from the asker's perspective - don't you think they'd like to see solutions as soon as possible?  Do you think this is some challenge to see who can gain the most reputation, which needs to be re-engineered to be more "fair"?  Wasn't the idea to help other developers solve the problems they face?

Comment: "I feel that lots of users simply want to make the quickest answer as possible to claim the reward of an upvote or acceptance." -- this is the answer to your question "why"

Comment: [I like answering posts which makes me elaborate my code and type a lot. Those answers (questions) are usually more complex and high rep rep hunters stays out of them anyway, giving me a better chance to take a better grasp (with more time) and work with optimal solutions.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17996112#17996112)

Comment: I started answering as quickly as possible (but only a correct answer that I could then elaborate on) because when I took the time to compose a long and complete answer, three or four others would come in, get upvoted, and one accepted before I could even finish. My answer would then languish, even if it was better & more complete than the accepted (and sometime wrong!) answer.

Comment: Instead of punishing fast posters with a system seeking to stop quick answers with many edits, as there are many who can actually fully answer a question in a matter of seconds, allow anyone to post as fast as they want, but they cannot edit until op's delay has expired. Instead of pushing older posts down the list, keep them up top. A hefty amount of downvotes will ensue thus enforcing the behavior we're looking for. *Always* punish behavior you don't want, lots of edits to hasty posts, not what you do want, quick-good answers.

Comment: @Aeron: Quite often, it seems to do what the OP wants, but there are many traps and corner-cases not adequately dealt with. Often it is very hard to impossible for a good answer to overcome the throng of voters searching for a quick and simple fix. Violation of "Make it as simple as possible, but no simpler." is often rewarded here!

Answer (score 66):

Users are answering questions as quickly as they can, so that they can get the reward of the acceptance - just as you suggest. If there was a minimum time, then the answerers would fight to post the answer at the instant that the time ran out, and possibly be duplicating others' work.

Downvoting a bad, rushed answer is a suitable deterent.

Comment: It would be if it worked. Naturally, there are droves of people upvoting those...

Comment: Gamification plays a part here, users lose rep for down-voting an answer and so are less likely to punish bad answers with a down-vote, because they are also punished.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to allow users to post answers, but for them not to appear for ~10 minutes? That way they can rush and answer, have time to improve it, and when the time expires the OP has a wealth of well-written answers to pick from?

Comment: @MattThrower Nice idea, but that also means that the OP has a wealth of well written *duplicate* answers to pick from, and a lot of people will have wasted their time writing the exact same answer as somebody else did. I think pretty soon this will result in people not answering at all, or just waiting past the 10 minute limit to see if the question needs their answer at all.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I don't see the problem. If you're not fishing for quick-shoot upvotes, you could either write a well-crafted answer to outclass the other ones or you write not-so-well-crafted answers for older questions.

Comment: @GolezTrol The current system still encourages lots of duplicate answers. Everyone rushes to put in a placeholder, then edits it, without looking to see how other answers are developing. A cursory glance at some of the simpler questions on the site confirms this.

Comment: @MattThrower If I post a quick answer, and somebody else has posted the same quick answer a tiny bit earlier, I either improve my answer to add value or remove it. I can do that when I refresh a couple of times after posting the answer. Sometimes it can feel like a contest, silly as it may be. But I won't do that if I have to wait 10 minutes first. In that case, it's fire and forget and soon the fun will be gone as well.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I disagree. When there's a grace period of ten minutes, I will have invested probably a few minutes already, such that I only wait like 4 minutes or so. In any case, I will re-check how it worked out after that time. If your answer is relevant, you will sooner or later get a vote anyways, which then appears at the top of this site, and many ppl will check what that was that they received a vote for. If you are not posting a plethora of answers each day, there is no context-loss, and fire+forget is the wrong attitude anyways and sounds a lot like vote-farming.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Not everyone is as disciplined as you.

Answer (score 52):

### Remove the incentive to shoot first, aim later*

Reset the timestamp on an answer when it has been substantially edited (>10 chars, 10%).

If an answerer substantially edits their answer, it is moved down the list.

This would(could) mean answerers are more careful when posting answers and subsequently revising them, as the 'unfair advantage' of simply posting a placeholder response to be 'first in line' disappears.

**Or... let others shoot the quickshooter**

Introduce a flag which marks an answer as abusing the timing system to garner votes.

In the review queue, compare the first revision of an answer to the most recent. If reviewers believe the user has abused the timing system, the timestamp on the answer is reset.

nb. This will likely introduce too much noise / overhead.

---

<sup>***Response to comments:** this suggestion is to address abuse of the system whereby a quick answer/placeholder is posted simply for the purpose of reserving a place in the answer queue, so the answerer can then go back and improve it with the hope it will gain upvotes from subsequent viewers through positional bias. This does not change the fact the answer will be visible throughout this time (unless the delete/undelete 'trick' is used - which this approach will prevent) and can gain upvotes. However if it does get votes in this time, it suggests it is already an answer of merit, so likely the subsequent edit *isnt* tactical and this doesnt apply.</sup>

Comment: Maybe ">10 chars"? Indeed.

Comment: @Vesper, I did mean >10chars, corrected :)

Comment: I though something like solution 1 would already be implemented. It makes too much sense that it's strange it isn't there yet. :p

Comment: Would it be possible to split this into two answers, one for each solution? I've already upvoted for Solution 1, but would like to downvote Solution 2.

Comment: @Deduplicator - not sure I follow?

Comment: Doesn't this already exist? it's just that "Active" is selected by default instead of "oldest". but "Active" is what should be default, otherwise some old stale answer will appear instead of newer possibly more relevant ones.

Comment: I don't see how the timestamp will change anything. The answer is still *visible* first, therefore it will get more votes.

Comment: I like your second point. I've often seen people leave almost blank answers and then edit them once they figure out the issue.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - this is to protect against poorly written placeholders being put in and being then substantially revised so a good answer appears first. If an answer is valid enough to be upvoted the first time round, that's fine.

Comment: How would resetting the timestamp help? Answers are sorted by votes by default.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once. I personally never post an answer until I have validated that the answer/code I provide answers the question (as best I understand it) AND functions as the OP requests. This has caused me to not post **many** well formed answers due to the fact that a poorly formed (and sometimes) wrong answer has already been accepted. **But** I stick to my guns... I will only post well formed and tested accurate answers. I prefer to have a higher answer to accepted percentage than high rep. Sad that ratio is not presented alongside rep scores. [cont...]

Comment: I feel it speaks more of the person who has answered 100 questions and 85 of those were the accepted answer (85% acceptance rate) than someone who has hastily answered 2000 questions and 150 were the accepted answer (7.5% acceptance rate). The higher ratio indicates that person provides better quality answers. Resetting the timestamp on substantially edited answers would "level the playing field" so to speak. The quickshooter who has now edited their answer to a better quality one is now in the same timestamp range as those who waited to provide a high quality answer in the first place.

Answer (score 23):

If that annoys you I can recommend doing what I do:

Don't care about the top half of the questions on the start page (or whatever page you use). Skip right to the end and answer/comment/... the questions there.

They are much more interesting to answer (because they actually need someone who is expert in the matter because all the easy stuff has been answered already) and you have time to write a proper one.

That way you don't have to compete with fast typists and there is no urge to add to the fast answers that need improvement in the grace period to be legit at all.

The only downside to this is that you won't earn that much rep, but well... No fake internet points... you're gonna survive.

Comment: Yes fake internet points indeed! - I have seen enough on SO to realise that reputation means nothing. For example a well timed "hell yeah!" comment on a popular question can give you 1000 rep. Which is a lot more than my total rep!

Comment: @MartinCapodici Well "nothing" is too less. In my personal perspective they have meaning: 1-20=new User; 21-1000=should know how SO works basically; 1001-10000=regular; >10000=Pro. - That won't work all the time, but is a good estimate and will alter the kind of comments I leave / edits I take. But seriously as soon as you are past a couple hundred rep it doesn't matter that much anymore. I rep farmed until I had 2k rep to see votes and be able to edit. After that, I didn't really care anymore.

Answer (score 18):

We could potentially fix this by giving a period (of perhaps 15 mins) after a question is posted during which down-voting an answer is free. This means that if someone genuinely makes a good answer very quickly they will be unaffected but someone who posts a rushed and poor answer purely to have the first post will more easily be shot down by a volume of down-votes.

In addition users who are more nervous of the down-votes can take the less risky approach and post after the delay so will also not be hurt.

As suggested by another commenter, these free down-votes could potentially be earned as a reward for gaining a certain amount of rep, however the details would need some thought.

The only flaw as suggested in comments is that this would allow answerers to down-vote other answers to make their own higher, this could be worked around by not allowing the perk of free voting to other answerers or removing down-votes you gave if you later answer.

In short: **Make down-votes free on answers of very recently posted questions**.

Comment: Could be OK, but I'd exclude those who provide an answer to the same question. Otherwise I could answer a question, and downvote all other answers to get my answer first.

Comment: @GaborSch Good point actually, Editing that in.

Comment: Perhaps the down-votes free could be for those with a minimum reputation to prevent the problem indicated by @GaborSch. I'm not sure I like the penalty approach, though - if someone is looking for a quick answer, then getting part of the answer out, whilst allowing time for the OP to provide feedback before an answer is refined can be beneficial.

Comment: @CJBS Stack Exchange is all about the community judging the merit of questions and answers in order to make the best possible knowledge base. I would not like to give a penalty to all fast answers by any means, I simply think people will judge these answers more fairly if they can do so without penalty, if they are of real value I trust the community will upvote them, however if they are indeed just a useless placeholder they will get downvotes as deserved. However the minimum rep idea is great, it could also be another interesting privilege to get.

Comment: @CJBS However I am adding a note about your suggestion to the answer as it could really help the idea. :)

Comment: @CJBS My opinion is that a minimum rep would not solve the issue, rather giving advantage to those who have higher rep. I would say that 1 free downvote per question within the grace period would be a better solution.

Comment: @GaborSch The idea behind the minimum rep (e.g 500) is to prevent new users from voting other answers down "for free" just to increase the prominence of one's own answer. Personally, I think that probably having all sorts of rules for this sort of thing is more or less unnecessary, as good answers to good questions will always rise to the top eventually, and poorly constructed questions and their corresponding answers will eventually be closed out and deleted. There's not necessarily a process/programmatic solution for each problem.

Comment: @CJBS "good answers to good questions" receive only 1% of total votes, IMHO. The problem is that those who cannot give "ga2gq" will also gain a lot of votes & rep with a simple trick, also devalvating the value of a good answer. Concerning the proposal: a rep limit of 500 would not block *me* (with rep >6k) to do this. Whatever limit we can set, we will always see that people just passing this limit will endlessly downvote their 'competitors' afterwards (as a revenge of previously received downvotes).

Comment: @GaborSch You're absolutely right. As with any system mitigation to one problem, there's most likely some side effect introduced as a result, hence my view that it's better to just let it play out. IMHO, the point of stackoverflow is to gain and share knowledge, and help others; reputation is just a mechanism to allow others to say 'thanks' to others for taking the time to contribute.

Answer (score 7):

## The problem

- Quickshooters will get early audience, that yields early votes
- Therefore they're motivated to give quick-and-dirty answer, and edit them later
- Most people sort the answers *by votes*, so early votes give the quickshooters unfair advantage over the more founded, but slower answers.

## A solution

I think this problem rises only in the **Sort by votes** mode, so this view should be changed, especially the ordering.

My proposal similar to @SW4's: If the answer is substantially edited (I'd say more than 10% of the text body has been changed), in the next 5 minutes (grace period) the ordering would order them **as if they had 0 votes**. After the grace period the answer would be ordered normally.

In addition (not to confuse the readers), **the number of votes would be hidden** during the grace period, and a question mark image would appear instead (so the vote result would not distract the reader from the content). Clicking on the question mark the readers could peek the actual vote counts. Voting is always enabled, regardless the status.

### Example:

```
+12 Answer 1
 +8 Answer 2
 +4 Answer 4
 +4 Answer 3
  0 Answer 7 <-- received no votes
  ? Answer 5 <-- recently edited 
 -1 Answer 6 
 -3 Answer 8
```

So, they would appear **in the middle** of the list, not at the bottom.

Comment: *"Most people sort the answers by votes"* What is the default? my guess is most people use the default.

Comment: @KevinB I think most people customize the view for themselves. Most people are seeking answers, so they want to see the best answer first. That's why I believe that the most common is "Sort by votes".

Comment: I checked, and the default is "Sort by votes".

Answer (score 6):

Two remarks:

1) Use this question filter:

```
score:0.. views:10.. answers:0..1 hasaccepted:0
```

That way, you'll avoid questions that invite people to shooting fast answers. Often, these questions have much more substance anyway.

2) Somehow it helps me if I know others are writing with me. I try to hurry, but in a positive way, as I personally wish to deliver a bit of quality also. I feel later that writing emails or other things also have a bit accelerated :-) So there is a positive aspect. If you are not the fastest to answer, why caring? Over time, statistics will give you your reward anyway if you have fun to continue long enough, and if it is your personal motivation not to collect points but to help each other.

Answer (score 4):

I feel that the site was designed around this. If you want to change it you change the design. The points system isn't just for bragging rights. I can't even make a comment on a question without more reputation. So to be able to actually use the site you're encouraged to answer as quickly as you can, which I think is unfortunate.

Comment: Not really. SO doesn't mind quick answers, because if the askers get quick answers they will keep coming back. You don't want to wait until tomorrow to get an answer when you're stuck with some piece of code, do you?

Answer (score 4):

Another good reason to answer first is to prevent other users to answer the very same thing as you did.

This won't prevent **all** copy-cat answers (a real **plague**), but some users won't post their answer if the very same or a similar one is **already there**.

There's nothing bad in making your answer better again and again, when you can rephrase a sentence to be more clear (or in a better English) or add a link or some code example.
Even some reformatting might be helpful to embellish your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The root problem is here the upvoting and not the quick posting of answers. What I am suggesting is that instead of delaying the posting of answers, we should delay the upvoting of those answers, similar as to the OP who can accept an answer only after a certain delay.

This will be a win win situation it will allow the posters to post but not to garner votes, hence users will go through all the answers as every answer still has 0 votes. After a certain time there will be a list of answers for which the users can vote.

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments, what if we allow voting but dont show the votes for some time. Just a message showing indicating that the vote has been recorded. That way it would prevent blindvoting.

Comment: That also means *bad* answers cannot be downvoted, and will appear more legit than they are. It also means barely anyone will get votes in any direction anymore, since most votes *are* cast when the Q or A is new, and I doubt people will stick around to wait before they can vote. Feedback in the form of votes is important for the SO system, delaying it is mostly as bad as removing it completely.

Comment: If an answer is good quality, I want to express my positive opinion *now*, and focus on other things. I don't have time to return to this questions after the grace period to vote AGAIN.

Answer (score 3):

This is especially egregious for hard questions.

There are lots of difficult questions in SO that get a lot of incomplete, half-baked or downright wrong or bad answers within the first days of being posted, all of which get quickly upvoted, overshadowing the actually thought-through, right or good answers that can come months or even years after the original question, most of which rarely get any upvotes.

It makes me wonder whether passers-by only ever get to read the wrong answers and keep upvoting those, or whether the threads are never seen again after the initial answer rush, in which case it begs the question of whether the original question was so important to get that much attention in the first place.

Either way it is not a good thing. The internet has already enough misinformation as it is, and the attention economy is directly at odds with good coding and good engineering.

There should be an alternative ranking algorithm for answers that takes into account WHEN the answers were upvoted and how many views they've had since they were written.

This way, a late answer with 10 upvotes would be shown above a rushed early answer with 100 upvotes if the rushed answer had received less than 10 upvotes after the late answer was published.

Comment: *There should be an alternative ranking algorithm* Already exists: sort on Activity. Further: there's no view count on answers.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea in your second paragraph, but I wouldn't want to make the asker wait much longer than they need to for an answer. Some good questions can be answered in a couple of minutes. There's also already a delay (12 minutes?) before the asker can accept an answer.

A five-minute period where all answers can be submitted, but are hidden, would solve the problem of the first answerer having an unfair advantage. Like Mark said, I think what would end up happening though is a bunch of people would post almost identical answers in that period. Then instead of the fastest gun in the west being rewarded, it would be a mostly random selection.

I think the accept delay gives people a fair chance to put together a decent answer and if the accepted answer is not the best, the best will often rise due to upvotes.

Comment: " I think what would end up happening though is a bunch of people would post almost identical answers in that period": **Happens anyway.**

Comment: Seems like there might be another option, what if they were to limit the number of edits a user can make to an answer in the first 30 minutes. IE, they answer something quick then they can only make one revision (or none, but sometimes people will actually make a legitimate mistake). I think that would eliminate people who rush to post since their initial answer would most likely be down voted while they continue to edit, but it doesn't make the answerer or valid answerers have to go through any of the waiting.

Answer (score 0):

People are answering questions as quickly and efficiently as possible to earn the reward. To discourage this behavior, people could just downvote the answer, but they may be disinclined due to the penalty the voter incurs for this behavior. I could go through every bad answer on SO and downvote away, and decay my score to nothing, for no real benefit to myself, but a minor, almost negligible benefit to the community.

Also, if you include a minimum waiting time before the OP can accept an answer, there may be potential bias (ie: the OP might just accept the answer with the highest score). To maximize the score for an answer, it must be correct, and submitted ASAP, so other readers can vote on it.

The only way to discourage partially complete answers while eliminating bias (paragraph 2) and encouraging community involvement without penalizing reviewers (paragraph 1) would be to gate answers. Make it so no answers appear in the first 30 minutes of a question being asked. If a bunch of people all come up with a quick, good answer, they all appear at once, and get equal exposure to OP and the community at large.

Comment: Maybe make downvotes free for answers delivered in under x minutes. Kind of like how you can't edit after 5 minutes.
If its that easy to answer, maybe the answer was on google or could've been delivered via chat. If the answer is useful, it needn't fear the free downvotes.

Comment: I don't think that would be a very fair approach. I've been able to copy-paste examples of my own code for an answer and have something of decent quality put together in under two minutes.

Comment: I think hiding answers for 30 minutes is extremely unproductive. Many times the OP has a comment or a request for clarification on an answer and if OP can't see the answer untill 30 minutes later the chance of the answerer still being around to answer any comments would be way smaller. It would also make it much less likely that someone spots a wrong answer and comments on it since after 30 minutes there's a good chance the question is seeing less visits.

Comment: "they all appear at once" essentially yes, but in a linear layout thus hindering "equal exposure to OP..." ME shows the being the first on the list generally gets you more votes and acceptances. This is often the case when someone answers correctly and quickly while op has gone to the bathroom or is editing their post only to come back and accept a lesser quality answer for seemingly no other reason than placement in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If a question can be answered by a quick, short answer (something like "use this function/api", I tend to give that as an answer and post it already.

That information should be enough help for OP to solve their problem.

Quite often I will then make additions, explain my reasoning in more detail, link the docs and add a fiddle, but those are all extra's without which the answer should suffice, although people tend to down vote questions that don't provide a complete drop in solution.

And yeah, since I put (and am going to put more) effort into an answer, I'd like to get the rep as well, so I like to be fast to have any chance to be seen at all. If a question is a relatively simple question, it will attract more answers, and I like to be first with my short answer, and be the best in the end. I know internet points won't save my life, but it's part of the game. Answering questions on SO is completely gamified, which it probably a big part of it's succes. But because of that, it feels as a game as well, and I sometimes find myself answering simple questions just to kill some time. ;)

I don't feel this rush on other websites/fora where there is no reputation system, and I will then spend more time on the initial answer. So I guess it's a consequence of the scoring system, especially since SO is so overcrowded that there is actual competition for the fastest answer. I think this phenomenon is less strong on the other SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

This one just popped in my head. Maybe it's good. Or not... You tell me.

## Substantial edits in the first 10 minutes reset the rep gained from the users initial answer.

**Why do this?**

1) A substantial edit (whatever percentage that is determined to be), is essentially a new answer. So treat it as a new answer by resetting the reputation gained from it. (We could either leave the upvotes on the question, or remove the upvotes as well.)

2) It will discourage quick answers that don't contain any useful information as users won't gain any rep from doing so.

Comment: no, that's just stupid idea

Comment: @mehow It's stupid? Care to explain?

Comment: I happen to answer questions and then I edit them within the first 10 minutes to add extra details etc and I am not a rep whore. Clearly, your idea would cause more harm than good to people like me

Comment: Editing is fine, but when you change the contents of the answer to the point that it is not even the same answer, then you clearly could have taken a little more time to create a better answer. As to your second statement, I would imagine most rep whores don't believe they are rep whores.

Comment: so are you implying that I am one?

Comment: @mehow I don't know anything about you. But your comment admits to doing exactly what this question is talking about and then says, "but it's OK because I'm doing it."

Comment: no, sorry but there are people who genuinely answer (sometimes in under a minute) and want to edit their answers later for greater details. that has nothing to do with repwhoring nor with what this question is about. I have just explained why i dont like your idea as it would harm those who genuinely answer **and not for the wrong reasons**

Comment: @mehow I don't think it would generally effect you unless you are doing those changes within the first 10 minutes of the question, and then revised it within those first 10. But you are clearly not doing that, so it would not be an issue for you. This would apply to answers that have structurally changed within a short period of time. It could be implemented on whether additional details were added as well. For example, adding new information, but not modifying the original text might not count as a change, but additional info. The 10 isn't a hard number, it could be tweaked as well.

Comment: I feel that this algorithm would be to complex and therefore would cause a lot of confusion and complains on meta which in effect would rise the amount of work both the community and moderators would have to do ( in case the reputation drawback was somehow reversable)

Answer (score -1):

Reward is nice, but it's not the main point (not for me anyway).  The point is coming up with a decent solution that solves the problem and if you have to work at it too long and then finally post, someone else may have answered exactly or close to what you did (or not as comprehensive or good) and if feels like a grand waste of time.

Answer (score -6):

Stack Overflow could make it cost one reputation point or so to make a second edit within 10 minutes. Though it will hurt fastest-guns and perfectionists alike, and perfectionists don't do any harm here.

Comment: But consider the asker *waiting* for an answer and asking further clarifications in immediate comments. Should the answerer then wait >10 minutes *after each comment*, just to avoid slowly eating up his reputation? (I also often correct minor typos immediately after posting.)

Comment: How many edits do you think would be enough? (and yes, I admit my idea is far from perfect)

Comment: @Jongware an asker who feels the need to ask for multiple further clarifications, and an answerer who addresses each of these by editing the question rather than e.g. taking it to chat and figuring out specifically what is causing conceptual difficulty for the OP, are not using Stack Overflow as intended.