# Should Stack Overflow do anything to discourage copy-cat answers?

Tags: discussion

This is just an introspection post, after I noticed some behavior.

On the easier and more direct questions, we often see "parrot" behavior as users scrabble to collect the low-hanging fruit of "easy points".

But should not this behavior be possibly controlled?

What are the programmatic metrics that might be used to control this behavior?

Suppose I ask, for example:

> How do I print 'Hello, World!' in Java?

Within just one minute, five users would attempt to answer it. But they are not really doing anything useful for Stack Overflow, if they all parrot one another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are users answering questions as quickly as possible?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible)

Comment: _I think, but am not certain_ research, examples?  Guessing doesn't do any good.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I think we discussed the "Why" part right?

Comment: @bluefeet - Caught me :P , but I happened to remove that part  just as you caught it I think

Comment: Yes @Coffee - and it has been discussed with relation to copy-cat answers there as well. :)

Comment: @Coffee Doesn't matter if you removed that, the same question applies - do you have any examples demonstrating this?

Comment: @bluefeet Do we *really* need examples of easy questions collecting many answers in a very short period of time.  This seems frequent enough behavior that you can't really avoid seeing as to allow it to be stipulated.  Providing an example or two is more likely to just pull the question off topic discussing specifics of just that example.

Comment: @Servy Considering the initial version which was edited included the _I think, but am not certain_ - yes, IMO an example instead of a hypothetical would have been helpful.

Comment: @bluefeet regarding example, how about one discussed recently in [Lots of duplicate answers on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/839601)?

Comment: The real problem is having five fastest-gun attempts rather than five votes to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But they are not really doing anything useful for StackOverflow, if they all parrot one another

This reflects a common mistake: asking for a solution that countless readers know instantly doesn't promote *copying* so much as it promotes *really fast answers that all say the same thing*. When an answer is either common knowledge or easily-derived from common knowledge, lots of folks will start answering simultaneously, and their answers will all tend to be fairly similar.

Contrast this with the much more insidious problem of folks taking *non-trivial* answers written by others and pasting them as responses to new questions, giving no credit to the original author...

As for what to do...

- In the former case, nothing. Why waste time worrying about answers that took no time to write? In particular, *do not* harass folks or accuse them of copying - you're just creating discord where none need exist. Assume good faith...
- In the latter case, flag: a moderator will delete the post and probably give the author a break in which to read [the attribution guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). If you want to be extra-helpful, leave a comment with a reference to the original post, and perhaps check the author's past answers for similar signs of unreferenced duplication.

Comment: The urge to copy this answer verbatim is hard to resist. :D

Comment: @Joe You're not supposed to copy it *verbatim*. Add typos. Introduce grammatical errors. Add a nonsensical phrase. Then, and only then, can you rest assured of flying under the radar!

Comment: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168)

Answer (score 9):

Lots of very quick answers is a signal of the question's *difficulty*, not of the question's *quality*.  There are plenty of questions that are good questions, but that are simply easy to answer.  Yes, there is a strong correlation between easy questions and bad questions (many easy questions are simply easily answered through research; it's actually hard (but possible) to come up with a question that's easy to answer but hard to research a solution to), but the fact that there is a reasonably large overlap between easy and low quality doesn't change the fact that they really are orthogonal properties of a question.

Because of this, at the very least, one should be *very* wary of any automated action.  It could potentially be appropriate to draw attention to such questions and put them in front of people as potentially problematic (i.e. through a review queue) but there needs to be some means of distinguishing the good easy questions from the bad easy questions.  And of course before considering drawing the attention of reviewers to these questions you'll first need to figure out what you actually think should be done with them.