# Is it bad practice to post a short answer first and then add details afterwards?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, code, fastest-gun

I have the habit of posting quick code-only answers to "simple" questions, and then add details / context later... for example on a question that I stumble upon in a review queue, that can be solved in 2-4 lines of "basic" code.

Usually I elaborate it within minutes, but obviously sometimes I get interrupted, and it takes a bit longer.

In my mind this makes sense because:

1. The OP can get on with his life immediately if he is satisfied with the solution.
2. Someone else might not waste time writing up the same answer while I fiddle around with my English grammar.

However, (at least) twice now I've received negative(ish) comments about the code-only nature of my answer before I got around to adding context.
This got me thinking that my answers are probably popping up in some review queue, so while I may be sparing one person from writing a duplicate answer, I'm wasting someone else's time on reviewing my answer, and possibly writing a comment.

I also tend to make lots of edits to longer posts because I feel like some sentence can be tweaked ever so slightly to clarify something, or I change my mind about the naming of variables (or whatever)... I feel this should be perfectly fine if it improves the answer overall, but I'm actually not sure because for instance votes that are already cast are not actually intended for the new revision (ie. in my opinion it's an improvement, but someone else may disagree).

Questions:

1. Is it bad practice to post something that you know is not going to be your final answer, such as a code-only answer - even though it will (probably) solve the OP's problem on it's own?
2. Is it bad practice to perform several edits in general? I'm looking for some "official" guidelines or recommendations for editing (your own) answers.
3. Do all code-only answers pop up in a review queue, and if so should I continue doing what I'm doing now, but add some very short text before my initial answer just to prevent that?

### Conclusions

I have posted the conclusions I drew from the discussion this question sparked in an [answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303630/3631281)

Comment: Well it will make you look like you are posting an answer quickly so you can get a badge for being the first to post and have an accepted answer.

Comment: Probably a cross dupe:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: I'm here firstly to contribute to a community that has taught me so much, secondly because I get a kick out of helping others, thirdly because I learn a lot about my field by researching and answering questions... and well, sometimes just to pass time. So I'm not too concerned what it makes me look like, and though rep and badges are cool, I quickly realized hunting them does not produce good reusable answers. I believe my answer history will show that I rarely aim at being the fastest gun. When I do it is because it can solve the problem fast and I know I can (and will) elaborate afterwards.

Comment: This is called FGITW (Fastest Gun In The West), and it's fine as long as you can live with the ramifications (downvotes for poor/code only answers that may not get reversed after your edit). I always prefer to write a somewhat complete answer (with text and code if relevant), post it, and then edit to flesh it out, but would never post a code-only answer.

Comment: How about also commenting the answer if you're about to add context later? The comment won't improve the answer in itself, of course, but at least you'd get less comments about the the missing context which you are already aware.

Comment: @eis: *"How about also commenting the answer if you're about to add context later?"* If you feel the need to do that, the answer is incomplete.

Comment: would it really be bad if you just include some disclaimer: "This is the basic code, I will elaborate further soon"? Wouldn't that show people that it's not a low effort answer but one limited by time that will be fixed

Comment: @Syberdoor that was my first conclusion to that suggestion too... However, I'm getting the impression that the best way to handle this actually is to spend a little bit more time to include a minimum of explanation, but force myself to completely ignore clumsy sentences and grammar - then edit to improve those... I think it would normally take me as long to write a disclaimer, since this is really only relevant on questions that can be answered in <30 seconds with 2-4 lines of code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to upvote or downvote this. I don't like those kinds of answers, i.e. I disagree; but the question says "Is it bad practice", with which I agree. What should I do now?

Comment: @MrLister If I understand you correctly it is not relevant whether you agree or not (you can indicate that by voting on answers or posting one) - see [What is meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): "*On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement*" - this is not a feature request, so "*For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness*"

Comment: Related, maybe even a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible

Comment: Expanding on an answer later is good. Supplying something half-assed because you want to 'get in first' isn't. A 'code only' answer is rarely a good answer. But a short 'you're foo-ing the bar, which doesn't work because you need to frobnicate it instead' - and then expanding on what's going on and why is fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't really agree. An answer that fixes the problem can often be given in a sentence or two, but added context can still be highly useful.

Comment: If I see your half-made answer, because you answered too quickly, I'm going to vote it down as a half-made answer/poorly made. if you edit it later and I do not see it.... well... :(

Comment: @eis NOPE. "An answer that fixes the problem" is not an answer. Stack Overflow is intended for every FUTURE visitors who want to check on our repository of knowledge. To increase the knowledge, a code only answer is crap. The fact is "helps" the OP is not enough to justify this kind of quality on the site.

Comment: The flip side to the "fastest gun" problem is when you work on a detailed answer, get everything fleshed out and well explained, then you notice "1 new answer to this question", you click it, and somebody else has said almost exactly what you were going to say. That's pretty frustrating too. The trick is to find the right balance. Put enough into the initial answer that it can stand alone. Then edit to expand as much as you want / can be bother to.

Comment: @MattBurland: yup, that can happen even with questions where FGITW doesn't apply.  I've had it happen to me many times (tens of times, at any rate) where I've done some work on a question that's been unanswered for an hour or more, only to find that someone else has also been busy beavering away at a similar answer at the same time.  They get an up-vote if their answer warrants it; the question gets two answers — and some long time ago I got a 'sportsmanship' badge.  Sometimes I get an up-vote too; quite often, I don't.  'Tis life on SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: True enough. I got one of those sportsmanship badges too.

Comment: @Malavos at that point (when you vote down crappy draft) consider commenting - as of now, system is designed in a way that makes this [fun and fairly safe trick](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253862/is-it-all-right-to-flag-very-new-answer-as-very-low-quality/289668#comment174083_289668). "this answer looks incomplete, why?"

Comment: @MattBurland,@JonathanLeffler - even more frustrating is when you don't do FGITW and polish a longer answer for some, just to finally get not a "1 new answer", but "question was deleted by the author"..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: very true. I've only had it happen a few times, but infuriating when it does.

Comment: @mikk3lRo, I think you should rollback that edit and submit an answer yourself. It is better to keep answers separate from the question.

Comment: @Trobbins - I kinda saw that coming... the point of posting the conclusions was to allow a future visitor to skip reading all the answers and comments, so in the end I decided it made most sense as an addition at the top... But I've followed your suggestion :)

Comment: The issue I've occasionally had with FGITW is that they will shortly after I post include content from my post, and within 5 minutes so there is no audittrack, I have been toying with not posting for 5 minutes, if I see the 1 answer posted message.  I've even had that with comments. life in SO, indeed

Comment: In the long run, it doesn't matter. You'll get to a point where your personal score won't matter as much - so early upvotes and early correct answers won't matter so much either. Once users stop chasing points, they tend to simply finish their answer before they post it instead of establishing presence. The end result is the same.

Comment: Rather than worrying about what we allow people to do without qualifying as FGITW, or the pressure they're under because of FGITW behaviour (which is neither outlawed nor stoppable, but a faux pas), we should instead have a system designed in a way that doesn't incentivize FGITW in the first place.

Answer (score 122):

You are welcome to post a first version of your answer as fast as you can, **provided it is already a correct and useful answer meeting our minimal standards**.

Regarding whether doing lots of edits is bad, there's a resounding no.
Just make them count. I think that the fact we got rid of auto-CW is a fairly strong signal for that.

And yes, most if not all code-only answers, especially if short, will go through the VLQ-queue, exposing it to lots of negative attention.
While most don't actually merit deletion, they are certainly borderline and most deserve a downvote and need an exhortation to the poster to improve at least slightly.
Don't try to game that by adding fluff though (depending on the amount that dirty hack might not even work), add an actual explanation.

[ryanyuyu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/4320665) suggested coupling this comment with the "Looks Ok"-vote:

> While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: That is pretty much the sort of comments I got - and the term "auto comment" makes me assume that the amount of time needed to add this comment is negligible, so I shouldn't feel too guilty for wasting the reviewers time. I don't agree with the final sentence though, code-only answers can be very useful in the long run too - even if additional information would be *even more useful*... but that's another discussion, which I believe there are plenty of other meta questions dealing with already...

Comment: When you have people who have a habit of posting large chunks of code as answers without *ever* explaining any of them, you *might* start to develop a disdain for their answering style, and possibly even be tempted to serially downvote their answers.

Comment: That "**provided it is already an correct and useful answer meeting our minimal standards**" part is *really important*. The criterion I apply (and recommend to others) is: "Suppose your network connection disappears / your power goes out / etc. the instant you post your answer. Is it useful as is? No? Then keep writing before posting."

Comment: _"the fact we got rid of auto-CW is a fairly strong signal for that"_ -- I had to do a little catching up just to understand that claim. But having read up on it, I would have to disagree. The [SE blog post documenting the removal of the feature](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) indicates that the main reason for its removal wasn't that lots of edits are good but rather than the feature itself had harmful effects, especially in the hands of the malicious. I personally think that large numbers of edits suggests earlier edits were poorly thought out.

Comment: Also, the comment that @T.J.Crowder has highlight, I think deserves emphasis in the answer itself. This is _incredibly_ important. Far too often, the quick-draw answer is _not_ a good answer meeting our minimal standards, and frankly a code-only answer almost never does. IMHO, it's important to address head-on this habit of the questioner to produce low-quality answers in a rush, with the intent to fix them up later. I.e. while I agree the behavior is not in and of itself necessarily bad, it is so often correlated with bad behavior, IMHO it might as well be discouraged as a matter of practice.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: You can easily have a dozen worthwhile edits, even if every single one counts: Adding references, examples, background, stats, general polishing it all, and so on. But sure, it's rare to have a post with so many good edits, unless they are done over quite a long period.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Like Deduplicator said, I once had a [very long answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309344/895932), edited many times (good edits!) over quite long period, and it went to CW, and I had to asked a mod to revert it back.

Comment: @justhalf: I never said that _all_ posts with large numbers of edits were bad. Just that a large number of edits is strongly correlated with poor posts. Deduplicator admitted as much. The reason for getting rid of auto-CW has nothing to do with any theoretical desirability of large numbers of edits (something that doesn't exist); just that as well-intentioned as the feature was, it was being abused.

Answer (score 44):

> Is it bad practice to post a short answer first and adding details afterwards?

No. It's the key to get high a reputation as the [Fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) :-)

Joking aside, I can see its benefits, especially notifying other users that you're already taking care of the question. I have often saved time by not writing up my own answer after I've seen a well-known user start an answer (and only dedicated some comments or edits onto his answer where I saw room for improvement or a different focus). I also do practise this technique myself.

> Is it bad practice to post something that like as a code-only answer that you expand later

Yes. You should always post a complete answer. You can fill in details later, there's nothing wrong with that, but a code-only answer is typically a bad answer. If it's really simple 2-4 lines of code, you should be able to spare at least one sentence of explanation.

Do only post *good* answers. They may be short, they may be partial, but they should not be bad.

In fact I use an inverse strategy myself: Start with the explanation of the problem and sketch out the solution, then hit the `Post` button. Only later, I add the complete code example, with comments, and revise my wording where it doesn't fit or I forgot to type a word or made a grammar lapse.

Comment: Indeed. When [Jon Skeet is not waiting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9147/195743) he posts complete answers in under one minute - so it is beneficial to not spend too much time on you own competing answer :)

Comment: "notifying other users that you're already taking care..." -- unless I miss something, stuff like that would rather go to question comments

Comment: @Bergi That's the reason for achieving 100k (me) within short period of time.

Comment: @gnat: Often enough users who comment don't write an answer. Also, this strategy only applies to questions where the answer is obvious (so that I trust those known users to answer it correctly and completely) where no comments (for clarification) are needed.

Comment: I think I understand. There is sort of a race, who answers first, right? And notification helps other racers see that they have lost the race and try another race, something like that?

Comment: @gnat: That would be the FGITW where the others "loose" (by not gaining reputation). I seldomly play that game these days. But I'm more referring to those low-popular questions where not much reputation is in the game, and where a certain amout of work goes into an answer; like those typical questions where the innocent OP is totally clueless and asks a dozen of related questions that could be answered by a dozen of duplicate links, and you feel the urge to help them. Seeing another user step in early, I win myself by not having to invest the time to come up with an almost identical post.

Comment: @gnat: Of course, sometimes it just happens. I didn't expect [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32240984/1048572) to become a race - rather one expert technical answer. I started to write an answer, and while I've seen other answers coming in during writing, I did not know any of those users or that they would provide high-quality answers, so I continued writing (without expecting it to "pay out" like that).

Comment: interesting, that's a bit different of what I thought. A different kind of race, a race to help. And it's not driven by rep gains, just a desire to help. And there are many willing to help, because the question is simple, and it is that simple so answers will be identical, and answers notification saves time to others willing to help, so that they can get to next simple question that also may benefit of quick help, correct? That looks like a beautiful picture

Comment: @gnat: Yeah :-) It really happened once that BenjaminGruenbaum an me posted *exactly* the same answer only seconds apart. We had a good laugh…

Comment: Joking aside, I can't see benefits to this (it should be considered anti-pattern, imo).  In fact, I can see far more benefit from adjusting the UX to specifically prevent this kind of thing.  Not by stopping people from posting "fast" answers and editing them, per se, but by preventing all answers from becoming visible to anyone other than the author of the answer for the first 15 minutes after the question has been posted.  Which allows people to post fast minimalist answers and then revise them if they want to, but removes the +rep rewards for doing so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, Jon Skeet frequently posts a short answer, then enhances it incrementally.  He is a master of FGITW.

Comment: @DavidWallace sure... but his "fastest gun" answer is usually better/longer than what I'd consider complete answer for myself. I'd say Jon comes with rocket launcher when it comes to FGITW.

Comment: @aroth I think preventing people to see existing answers would help anything - all answers will go without reviews/votes and people who actually care likely stop answering to avoid wasting efforts... (I suspect that this suggestion discussed many times in the past, but if you interested making separate question may be good idea).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - That was just one example of an approach that would mitigate FGITW without discouraging prompt answers.  Others are possible (for instance, show all the answers but just suppress voting/accepting until 15 minutes have elapsed).  Though realistically I don't think suppressing answers for 15 minutes will cause them to go without review/votes.  The majority of voting, particularly on highly-upvoted questions/answers, occurs outside of the first 15 minutes of the question's lifetime.  And also you have to count the people who stop answering because they're sick of FGITW.

Answer (score 35):

I can't go so far as to say that it's "bad practice", but it *is* incredibly annoying. It shows that you are racing towards getting the most upvotes, not giving the OP the best advice. Of course you can improve your answer at any time, but deliberately posting an unfinished version just to "beat everyone else" is called being *the fastest gun in the west* and, last I checked, it was discouraged.

Comment: +1! I also found some guides online "How to be cool on SO" and they all suggest that. Important is to be the first, possible with a 3 word answer. Then click edit immediately and go from there. This behavior is also encouraged and defended by SO Staff, High reputation users and Jon Skeet, which reflects the true nature of SO. In my own questions, I'm downvoting all these idiots just out of principle!

Comment: Racing in the orbit is more fun than racing towards getting the most upvotes :)

Answer (score 20):

Ok, so a few days in this question has attracted a lot more attention than I expected, and it has taken a turn I didn't expect - I thought I stopped playing [**Fastest Gun In The West**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) a long time ago, but clearly I still am.

I will not mark any answer as accepted; who am I to judge a subject that much more seasoned SO users can't fully agree on. I'll let the votes speak for themselves.

Instead, here are the conclusions ***I*** drew from the discussion to summarize for future reference (TL;DR at the bottom)

1. Don't ever post **long** code-only answers - they are useless for future visitors (I never have, never will - and that type of answers were not the subject of my questions at all, but did come up in discussion).
2. It is OK to play FGITW - in fact it is one of the things that make SO so popular. There is no clear consensus on whether playing FGITW is good or bad - or rather: there is no clear consensus on the exact rules of the game (which is only natural in the wild wild west I suppose).
3. It is **not OK** to post a *placeholder*. All initial answers **must** comply with the *minimal standards* - which I cannot find(!) though I easily found a description of a [*good answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Lacking an official description of what exactly *minimal standards* imply, I will repeat the criterion suggested by [T.J. Crowder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder): "*Suppose your network connection disappears / your power goes out / etc. the instant you post your answer. Is it useful as is? No? Then keep writing before posting.*"
4. You can always make your OK answer into a good answer or your good answer into an excellent answer no matter how many edits it takes - but never post a crappy answer even if you intend to improve it.
5. Code-only answers **can** meet the *minimal standards*, but **rarely do**. Therefore most of them pass through the *Very Low Quality* review queue, and get a lot of negative exposure, even if they solve the problem at hand. Do not try to cheat your way around this mechanism by adding static to your initial post.
6. If you do post a quick half-assed answer to get in first, it is likely that someone going through the VLQ-queue will downvote or negatively comment on it before you can elaborate, and it is unlikely that this will be reversed even though the quality of your answer increases. Don't worry about the fact that you are causing this extra "work load" though - the effort needed is minimal.
7. You **can** write a disclaimer stating "*I am currently elaborating on this*" in a comment or in your answer **in addition** to your initial answer that meets the *minimal standards* - however, adding this "static" is as likely to further annoy someone who already dislikes your answer, as it is to convince anyone something better is on it's way... so I doubt *I* will do it.

Yes, I am aware that there's a minor conflict between `5` and `7`, but since `7` was a popular suggestion I wanted to include it anyway - get on with your life!

### Bottom line(s):

- The current state of the system clearly and actively encourages playing FGITW - this ensures that "what's wrong with this code" questions are usually answered really fast.
- But the system is also very effective in sorting through posts and giving more long-term attention to questions and answers of a more general nature - typically not those that are subjected to FGITW games.

**You can earn a lot of rep by being a sloppy, but fast gun slinger. If you want actual recognition you will need to shoot accurately.**

Comment: "The current state of the system clearly and actively encourages playing FGITW" - Which is the real problem here.  It ought to be changed so that it clearly and actively _discourages_ FGITW.

Comment: @aroth, You're seeing only one side of the story. There is [another camp](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62795/159916) which says that it's thanks to FGITW that SO gets so viral / hot / huge traffic (=== $$).

Comment: I thought the goal was quality, not traffic/going viral?  Besides you can have "fast answers" without relying upon or encouraging FGITW (which as I see it is not simply answering quickly, but going out of your way to get the _first_ answer even if it means leading with an answer that is not as complete or thorough or thoroughly tested/cross-referenced as you initially plan on making it).

Comment: @aroth, Had thought the goal was quality too. | There's two camps and your comment above does not accurately reflect the current state of the system.

Comment: I think you're misrepresenting the position of the other camp, at least based upon the answer you linked to.  That answer says that "fast answers" are beneficial, not that FGITW itself is beneficial.  It does not appear to defend or endorse FGITW specifically.  My point isn't that fast answers are bad, just that you can encourage fast answers _that are also good_ without encouraging/while actively discouraging FGITW.

Comment: @aroth, I think you've not read [*"I do NOT want to, in any way, discourage the quick and dirty answer"*](https://goo.gl/ozs6BJ). Also, read the answer in context of the question. It is endorsing FGITW because of the context of the thread [*"Why do we reward fastest answers?"*](http://goo.gl/dMXkTx). By reducing the answer's content to the [truism](https://goo.gl/OfuyTT) *"fast answers are beneficial"*, you've effectively removed the crux of the answer and made it meaningless within the context of the question.  Yes, [FGITW has benefits](http://goo.gl/ew9gSX) and it's..........................

Comment: ...............................................................................here to stay because [*"As long as the answer is good within the short editing window, then the purpose of the site has been served - a question got an answer"*](http://goo.gl/mcGdTX). In case it's not clear, none of those are my words. I'm merely showing you the position of the other camp.

Comment: @aroth - they took the work *quality* out of *The Tour* and the charter for the site a **long** time ago. It is now clearly about **quantity**, *quality* be damned. *quantity* drives clicks, clicks == revenue. Directly from `The Tour` page at the very top. *we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.* Search for the word *quality* ...

Comment: Good answers *inherently* take time, because a) they *explain* stuff, which is hard; b) they require good *questions*, which entails waiting for the question to be improved. Better yet, *truly engaged* answerers with an interest in offering the best possible answer (and with the necessary reputation already) would take a hand in editing the question, after making sure of exactly how it should be presented.

Comment: @user177800 FWIW, it now says "detailed, high-quality answers". However, that is inherently incompatible with "every question" - at least, with how the people asking the questions understand "every question".

Answer (score 4):

Why not add a line stating your intentions? Something like:

*I am currently editing in an explanation of the above code.*

Then, provided you actually finish the answer, you get to be the fastest gun without adding to the pile of crap answers. That said, a temporary code-only answer can still be problematic.

Depending on the question, posting code-only answers can reinforce the "give me the code" mentality where stackoverflow is used to outsource the mental faculties of the questioner. Adding an explanation (and perhaps slightly generalized code instead of something that they can plug in) helps the *questioner* appreciate what this site is about.

So try to post *some* explanation. If it's a couple lines of code, you can probably get away with a sentence that takes 20 seconds to write.

Example:

---

```js
var foobar = $("foo").bar();
var foo = foobar.foo;
var bar = foobar.bar;
```

Just use jquery to create a foobar object. The raw foo and bar objects are stored as properties.

---

*1st edit*

```js
var foobar = $("foo").bar();
var foo = foobar.foo;
var bar = foobar.bar;
```

Just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to create a [`foobar`](http://jquery.com/foobar) object. The raw `foo` and `bar` objects are stored as properties. You can of course do this without jQuery ([shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120786/728393)) but it takes a lot more code and jQuery should be used in all web projects anyway. etc.

---

But, realistically, a few seconds makes a difference when you are playing fastest gun (because questioners often don't know better). And since (in practice) you are rewarded for this behaviour, it's going to keep happening.

**So at least commit (publicly) to adding an explanation ASAP. Better than nothing. And make sure your answer isn't just a placeholder while you finish it (this is cheating). It needs to actually be a useful answer when first posted.**

It's also possible to have excellent code-only answers ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality) & [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262695/new-answer-deletion-option-code-only-answer)). But they usually take longer to write than a simple explanation.

Comment: -1, "and jQuery should be used in all web projects anyway"

Comment: +1, "and jQuery should be used in all web projects anyway", cause I feel bad that @Zanon didn't get the joke.  Also, I tend to put something like "I can add more description later if anything is unclear" in my fastest gun answers, and then I actually follow up and add more if someone comments and asks.

Comment: @GeneralMike there aren't any -1s to be fair.

Comment: @slicedtoad: oh, look at that.  I didn't actually check to confirm that he downvoted before I posted that comment.  You can still keep the +1 though - this is still close to the answer I was going to write myself.

Comment: Meta commentary in posts is discouraged. If you haven't got a complete answer **don't** post it. There's nothing wrong with posting a complete answer but then improving it, but partial answers to try to ensure you're first aren't welcome.

Comment: @ChrisF What about complete answers where you have the intention of making them better? I don't see how a small meta message that lasts a few minutes can hurt anything.

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything or anyone, just looks tacky. If you intend to flesh out your answer, just do it.

Comment: *"And since (in practice) you are rewarded for this behaviour..."* I'd like to challenge that. I found, even early on at SO, that being first was **not** as important as being **clear** and **thorough**. Time and again I'll see a question with a FGITW answer which isn't worth editing to improve (if it is, I'll do that; hopefully the answerer takes the hint), post a full answer, and find later that it's been A) Upvoted past the earlier one, and B) Accepted. I've also posted half-answers and been rightly trumped by someone doing the job properly later (and hope to have learned from it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, makes sense. I only played the FGITW game for a short while before getting bored and moving to a specific js plugin tag that I could actually write good answers for without having to rush. But I would say that it _feels_ like that's the best way to get rep when you are browsing new questions in a high frequency tag (like a language tag). Which is why it's such a common game of course.

Comment: "Why not add a line stating your intentions?" - Why not finish your answer before posting it?  That's the rational thing to do, instead of posting an answer with a note that says "I'm still working on this" (and which implies "I'm posting an unfinished product early because of FGITW").  The problem is that the current UX essentially punishes you for doing the rational thing and taking the time to ensure you have a complete, thorough, high-quality answer _before_ you hit 'Post'.  It's a problem that there appears to be little interest in actually fixing.

Answer (score -2):

Why not have a checkbox that allows authors to *tag* their posts as *"Draft—Currently editing"*? Draft posts will be subjected to the same strict guidelines as normal posts. In fact, they'll be *exactly* the same as normal posts except for two areas:

1. If the author doesn't update the post by `x` minutes, posts that are tagged as draft would be hidden from the page. (As such, if he had a train disconnection, or if he fell asleep while typing, the draft posts would then automatically be hidden after `x` minutes.)
2. A different UI from normal posts, so users are able to tell draft posts apart from non-draft posts.

Of course, when it's time's-up for the draft, the draft is not deleted. It is merely hidden from public view and the author can continue again when he gets back online. He might either discard the draft or publish it depending on the state of the thread at that point in time.

---

In fact, while we at that ;) why not have another checkbox to enable auto-drafting in "websocket time"? Which means, whatever the author types gets [published automatically](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186749/24257) as a draft as long as the checkbox remains checked. Soon we'll be seeing Area51 proposals like  CodeRace.SE or TopCoder.SE.

Feature creep ftw.

Comment: "Draft posts will be subjected to the same strict guidelines as normal posts." Wouldn't displaying draft posts differently from normal posts run foul of that then?

Comment: @BoltClock, The same strict guidelines are with regards to the content of the posts, the so-called "minimal standards" that the post must adhere to. Until a draft post becomes *official* it will have a different UI, such that users would be able to tell that it's a draft post which will either be further updated by `x` minutes, or hidden from public view.

Comment: This seems essentially like just automating @DanielST's suggestion.

Answer (score -13):

Code only answers are fine for answers that just correct a code-typo. The questioner will quickly find the fix because they are familiar with their own code and can spot your improvement. And as pointed out by the comment votes: Also vote to close the typo question as non-reproducible (assuming the typo is fixed).

For other code only answers, take 10 seconds to throw in a quick but useful code comment and head your answer as "Here's some annotated code regarding *******". Then later expand upon your code comments.

If your answer involves more than short code then why not wait the extra few minutes to get the answer fully formed. If you *feel absolutely compelled to pull the trigger* on a 90% answer (or a 100% answer that lacks sufficient explanation), then at the very least you should be able to make it 100% within the 4(?) minute still-an-original-answer grace period allowed. By giving a 100% answer within a very short period, you will likely avoid having someone get annoyed by the 90% code.

And by all means, if you later think of an improvement or an omission you can do an edit/update.

Comment: Being picky, the proper way to handle code-typos is to comment and _close the question_ for off-topic > can no longer be reproduced/typographical error.

Comment: @ryanyuyu. Agreed. :-)

Comment: So not fine for answers that just correct a code-typo...?

Comment: @BillWoodger unless it's a common typo, is unlikely to help anyone else. So it should be closed instead of answered.

Comment: @slicedtoad yes, I was hoping for a change to the wording.

Comment: Especially with typos it is better to point out the actual error, than to dump code with the error corrected (leaving it to the reader what the differences is and why it would fix it). Never, leave code only answers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Of course. A good code only answer shouldn't present excess code to the point of confusion and I'm certainly not suggesting a "code dump"! But if there is a typo: `contexxxxt  // s/b context` really should be an adequate answer along with a vote to close as being non-reproducible after the typo is fixed.  If the error exists in about a half-dozen lines then, as I explain in my answer: (1) show the corrected half-dozen lines, (2) add a quick code-comment to explain the change, (3) Put a short, descriptive header over the code to explain the change.

Comment: @ryanyuyu that isn't "being picky"; that's upholding the core principles of the site. Writing an answer for such questions is explicitly making the site worse by interfering with the cleanup process (i.e., increasing the likelihood that a question that should get Roombad or manually deleted won't be).