# submit incomplete answer and edit it later

Tags: discussion, answers

I see people (I do that too sometimes) answering a question with an incomplete but good answer (think of submitting code without explaining or writing a short answer) and editing it later to complete it.

They do this to make their answer the first one or just to save the answer from time to time just in case.

My questions are:

1. May I submit an incomplete answer and edit it later to complete the answer?
2. Should I downvote incomplete answers that I see?
3. If you answer yes to 2, when the user edits it to make it a complete answer should I undo the downvote?

[Is it bad practice to post a short answer first and then add details afterwards?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303446/is-it-bad-practice-to-post-a-short-answer-first-and-then-add-details-afterwards)
only ask and answer my first question

Comment: 1. You can answer however you want, as long as you're aware of: 2. and 3. You should vote on the quality and correctness of the answer.

Comment: it only ask and answer the first question

Comment: it will be closed as two dup and one too broad

Comment: about 2 and 3 you said `You should vote on the quality and correctness of the answer` but i told you it's good correct answer but only code so does that mean it worth down vote or not ?

Comment: also what is the `minimal standards` for answer ?

Comment: You should consider reading the [help], it sounds like you haven't taken the time to familiarize yourself with the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> May I submit an incomplete answer and edit it later to complete the answer?

You're *allowed* to.  As to whether or not it is a good idea is going to depend on just how complete it is.

> Should I downvote incomplete answers that I see?

You should evaluate the quality and usefulness of the answer, as it is, and vote on that.  If the answer is a useful answer *as it sits*, then you can upvote it; if it's not a useful answer *as it is now*, then vote accordingly.

> If you answer yes to 2, when the user edits it to make it a complete answer should I undo the downvote?

You're certainly not obligated to keep track of every post you ever vote on and update the vote if the post is edited.  If you happen to note that the value of the post has changed, you may choose to alter your feedback (a.k.a vote) accordingly.