# Discouraging post-and-edit

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

On a recent SO question of mine, one respondent answered very quickly with an answer that was wrong. I checked the code and found that it did not work, started to comment, and saw that this person had edited his answer. Refreshing, I saw a *completely different* solution. This cycle repeated. In the end there were four versions of the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41251365/revisions

Could SO discourage this sort of behavior? Should they?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303446/

Comment: SO got pretty famous for very fast answers to questions, if that has gone out of style then I missed the memo.  Implementing some kind of artificial "you have to think for 15 minutes before you post" rule makes about as much sense as posting a snarky comment back to somebody that spared a half hour of his free time to try to help you.  SO is not a personal help desk, all that matters is that an answer is useful for the next ~10 years to thousands of programmers.

Comment: If an answerer has to rewrite their solution several different times, it's very likely because your original question was insufficiently clear.

Comment: How dare you!  YOU are the fake Will.  I am the one and only true Will!  Is there but one Washington?  And is there but one Lincoln?  And is there but one Will?  I'm Will.

Comment: @Will We can settle this with two candles and our hands. ;)

Comment: But you *won't*. *ba-dum-tss*

Comment: This is Martijn's usual answering style, so I'd be leery of anything that approaches discouraging him from posting. His initial posts are kind of an early-access beta version, with the "official release" following soon after (sometimes after a few more release candidate revisions).

Comment: @CodyGray In this case I even posted an executable JavaScript code snippet that showed the issue; I'm not sure how to make the question any clearer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251313/reset-multiple-select2-when-loading-array-data/41251365

Comment: I'd agree this is a duplicate question; thanks to @gnat I think the "root" question is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 25):

> Could SO discourage this sort of behavior?

Sure, easily. Many forums *lock* posts as soon as they're created, preventing them from ever being changed. Some provide a small grace period for fixing typos, but lock it down forever once this is done. Obviously, this precludes extensive editing... And having all of your mistakes forever on display would seem to be a deterrent as well.

> Should they?

Well... I'm sure you've at one point or another ended up on one of the forums I described above. How'd you like wading through a few pages full of knee-jerk half-assed answers looking for one that actually worked?

Answers on Stack Overflow often last for years. In general, it's much more important to have answers that are *correct* long-term than to worry about how they looked at various points in the first day of their existence. If someone's willing to recognize their own mistakes and fix them, that's worth encouraging.

Comment: Exactly. This question seems counter to one of the great things about this network. I can stroll into a 5 year old question with my current, valid solution and post it. In fact we reward that behavior with badges. Or I can update my old answers to respond to standards changing or software changing. You remove that, and this network can get stale pretty quick

Comment: This seems to answer the inverse of the posted question, referring to content that can _only_ be changed for a few minutes (generally to correct typos), while the question is about whether answers should be posted only once they're complete, _without_ edits in the next few minutes.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: If you're implying that the software should prevent posters from making edits *until some time has passed* (thus locking in initial impression votes), I'd suggest you post that as an alternate approach to the problem. Seems interesting. Shog's description refers to forums using a different theoretically valid solution, simply locking in the basis for all responses after a short time (presumably to prevent any major edits). Both are technical *solutions*, though.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I think the difference is that making edits available for a few minutes but no longer, as with comments, is intended to allow users to address typos, while making edits available indefinitely is intended to allow users to improve their posts with new information over the years. The combination of those - editing a post with substantial amounts of new information in the first few minutes - seems to be a bit of a corner case.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah, SE software doesn't *currently* implement much of anything to discourage this, technically. It could, but SE has rejected one possible solution (described here). I think your alternative may be worth examining in more detail, though.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Although it can certainly be disconcerting to see a post evolve like that, I think the harm in such a style is minimal (it's theoretically possible for a reader to see such an incomplete post and immediately rush off to use a non-working code fragment or something, I guess). Weighed against the eventual quality of some of those posts, I don't think such a restriction is worth it.

Comment: Incidentally, I've addressed the "typo" scenario at length elsewhere (along with some stats on how common it is); if you're interested, I can dig up a link.

Answer (score 21):

If someone posts an answer that's wrong, downvote it.

That's how you discourage people from posting wrong answers.  If they learn that their post needs to actually be good enough for an upvote before the first post it for it to actually be received positively, then that's what they'll do.

Comment: I actually did; the catch is that this person's last edit was a viable answer and could help future readers. In that (edge) case it seemed unfair to leave him with a -1. In general your answer makes sense.

Comment: I'd have no bad feelings "forgetting" about the downvote in this scenario.

Comment: If an answer is a good answer in it's current condition, why would you downvote it? Is it to confuse future readers who will wonder why that viable solution is not correct or harmful?

Comment: @TinyGiant You would down vote the answer while it's wrong.

Comment: I would add to this advice that in [meta-tag:fastest-gun] context a helpful trick is to [accompany downvote with quick brief comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601), eg "this answer seems wrong"

Answer (score 3):

> Refreshing, I saw a completely different solution. This cycle
>   repeated.

I am guilty of that a lot.  And this is the main reason I am drawn to answering questions here rather than on other forums.  The ability to rethink/refine and ultimately correct your own answers and admit your mistakes is a good thing(TM).  In fact, that is why the comments exist.  Their purpose is to suggest how the forever-editable content (questions and answers) can be made better.  That's not how comments are always used (because sometimes the bar for posting actual answers is too high), but that is their intended purpose.

Comment: I agree that refining answers is a good thing. I dislike "quick-draw" answers that are flat-out wrong or inapplicable, whether or not these are refined later. (I suspect you do your best to avoid that.) :)