# How to deal with unclear questions and their lightning-fast ("fastest gun in the west") answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, fastest-gun

I often come across (initially) low-quality questions, while *I have a lot of questions for details*, usually leaving them as comments (with the hint to edit, not to comment).

Usually I come across these answers during reviews, but also via the front page when looking for tags on topics I could potentially help with. So there might be topics I'm familar with, where I could help. But I fail at understanding the problem or I'm getting more questions about the problem when trying to formulate a complete answer.

Such question typically look this (one or more points apply):

- "I have a problem with this *bunch of code, library, framework, tool*" plus some code, commands or links
- Either the use case, error messages, the steps to reproduce and/or the expected and actual results are missing
- No sign that the questioner did something to isolate the problem (show what she/he has tried, shows use of the debugger etc.)
- The question smells like [the X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and more details would help to give quality answer that solves the cause rather than kind-of fixing the `break` statement of some 50-case `switch` clause (curing the cause of the itch instead of sedating it)

While typing my request(s) for details (as comment), new answers appear. It's not uncommon that there are 5 answers within 10 minutes.

Most of these answers, in my opinion, *do not* or really can't address the questioners problem.

I am aware of the [fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) or [why users are answering questions as quick as possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible), but both posts seem not to address the problem of lightning fast answers *to incomplete/unclear questions*, which, I'd say, is a special problem.

My questions are:

- Should I also treat the fastest guns? (And not just the question)
- How should I treat them? (Downvote, flag, just comment?)
- Should I raise a moderator flag as soon as I notice such behaviour instead of commenting the question to ask for details?

It's clear to me that a low-quality answer could evolve to a OK-ish, so hasty downvotes would be unfair (but how should I know when the answer is finished? >:] ). I'm aware that I could change my vote later, but I simply won't track them over hours. Deletion due to some flag can be discouraging and won't add value to the community. Leaving them on the other hand could decrease the community value too.

Comment: Personally I would say: Take your time use comments for clarification under the question and then if you think you understand everything you can write an answer if you want and think you can help the OP; For the answers: wrong answer -> DV (+ optional: comment); incomplete answer: (+ optional: comment);

Comment: *hasty downvotes would be unfair* Why?

Comment: patience and prompting OP to recognize an XY problem will often prevail. Most of the fast guns are long gone when you finally help OP get to the crux of the issue

Comment: Yeah, hasty downvotes to hasty answers to unclear questions seems fair to me. Sure, they could edit it after the fact, but did they have to post it ASAP? Of course they did, that's the FGITW mentality. What they don't realize is that they didn't actually have to.

Comment: And between not adding value, and potentially decreasing value, which would you prefer?

Comment: I'd say you should leave the answers alone unless you are 100% sure they are wrong/incomplete (esp because you've indicated that you won't check back on them). It is very much possible that they've understood the question better and clearer than you and it is incorrect to downvote answers just based on your perceptions. I've run into many such cases where I've asked 4-5 questions in comments but found that somebody else has given a perfect answer without need for extra clarifications. This can happen due to language barriers and users from same area as the OP could've understood better.

Comment: We cannot avoid FGITW answers but not all FGITW answers have to be wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock: Hasty answers to 100% unclear questions is fair but not if there are only 1-2 users thinking that the question is unclear while others find it perfectly clear. There is a fine line between hasty FGITW answers and fast answers that are indeed correct. (For example, many questions that I can't comprehend, you answer within minutes :D Because you've got more expertise than me in the area to even see the hidden meanings)

Comment: I completely agree with Harry. Sometimes I've answered questions because they were completely clear for me, while other were asking for clarification in comments. And vice versa too. I don't think it's fair to downvote an answer because you don't understand the question, and I think pnuts is spot on with their answer.

Comment: Obviously by "unclear question" I meant questions that are generally accepted by most people as unclear, where *nobody* but the OP can verify if an answer is indeed the answer to the question and people answering are simply throwing mud at the wall and seeing what sticks. Of course there are cases where one or two individuals just completely fail at reading comprehension and either completely misinterpret the question, or the answers.

Comment: And there are questions about obscure topics that only domain experts can answer (thanks @Harry). There too is a fine line between an unclear question, and a clear question about a topic that is not widely understood. In the latter case, you can very clearly tell what is being asked - you just don't have sufficient knowledge of said subject.

Comment: By hasty answer, I mean answers that jump in with "have you tried this" or "try this it's working fine" "try this" "try that", where it sounds as though the answerers themselves aren't entirely sure what the OP is asking either.

Comment: Agreed there @BoltClock. Those should definitely be frowned upon.

Comment: @Harry they generally are. If I happen across such I usually downvote them and its not just me doing that.

Comment: related: [Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274919/839601)

Comment: I recently answered a question that already had an accepted answer with 4 votes that was posted 2 minutes after the question. My answer was 10 hours late but the question asker switched the accepted answer to mine. So I do think quality answers are appreciated by askers http://stackoverflow.com/a/33178951/704803

Comment: In my (limited) experience there is no black and white here, only grey. With many posts, I have some idea of a solution or direction that might work, of the type 'here is 10 lines of code, is that what you are looking for?'. Sometimes this turns out to be what OP wanted, sometimes triggers more comments/ updates on question from OP. I also see many questions without any answer, where OP has left a last comment in the comment-thread that his issue is solved based on comments only. Fast guns are not always bad. And bad is not absolute: one person's bad answer, may be another person's solution.

Comment: @gnat - Why link a closed question? The canonical answer to that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/1026459

Answer (score 88):

The goal of this site is not letting everyone who has read an introductory course to programming showcase their "knowledge". It's to build a great collection of high-quality questions and answers.

Answerers, and especially newly registered ones, need to learn that they are not here to guess OP's problem and copy-paste their favorite bit of code that solves most of their problems.

A question should be clear. If it isn't, don't answer. Period. Use comments to ask for clarification and in the meantime, immediately close-vote as "Unclear" or "Needs to include relevant code" or "Cannot reproduce". You can always re-open if OP bothers to add details.

So please, for all that it's worth, [downvote any answer that says *"Try this [code block]"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811), or that in any other way does not demonstrate that they understood OP's problem. A small explanation of OP's problem in your answer should be mandatory, and I vote based on that.

Especially when you have more than the slightest programming experience, and preferably some experience in the tag or language that the question is about, you can quickly determine that a question is unclear or incomplete. So use your experience and passion for the site to downvote answers that don't add quality to the site. The latter is done not enough anyway.

Comment: I wish there were more people like you and I. Actually, I wish everyone were like you and I. But they're not... and they never will be. Which takes us back to .... alcohol.

Comment: @Lightness *hic*. Tjanks.

Comment: For an extra point, replace _"knowledge"_ with _"passion"_, and _"question"_ with _"doubt"_ ;)

Comment: You got an upvote because I mostly agree with your answer. Especially paragraph 2 and 4 touched me. Though I'm still not 100% sure how to deal with hasty answers (or whether I should vote and/or flag depending on the content).

Comment: +1 This should be marked as the correct answer so everyone will see it first thing before getting all kinds of bad ideas (and alcohol) into their head.

Comment: Terrible answer.  Do not downvote questions just because you don't understand them in your initial skim.  You should only downvote questions as "unclear" if it's clear that they would be unclear to every possible answerer, and not just to you.  And the fact that someone else is answering the question indicates that it is clear to someone, if not to you.

Comment: Answers that are useful for the original poster clearly show that the answerer understood the original post, and thus that the original post was not unclear.

Comment: @Warren no, it doesn't. Given any error message than can have many different causes, a guessed answer that gives a solution for one of those causes (while only one is correct), without explanation, is not a good answer and does not make it a good question. I'm also not talking about questions that _I_ don't understand, I'm talking about exactly that situation: where I, through experience, _know_ there isn't one possible answer and that OP _needs_ to add details in order to get their question properly answered.

Comment: If the answer addresses the correct cause, the most likely way that happened is that the answerer noticed relevant details that you missed, not that he just made a wild guess.

Comment: My original comment had to do with downvoting questions, not downvoting answers.  In my experience, a large majority of question downvotes are because the downvoter doesn't understand the question, even though the question is often clear to me, so I think "people downvote what they don't understand" is pretty valid for questions.  I do agree that people don't tend to downvote answers because they don't understand them.  On the other hand, answers of the form, "this is what worked for me" I think are still useful answers, so I don't downvote "try this" answers unless they are wrong.

Comment: And to clarify further, what I object to the most is not so much question downvotes, but rather the fastest gun close votes.  And I would even agree that part of that problem is that it's so much easier to close vote than to vote against closing.

Comment: -1 for "OP's problem and copy-paste their favorite bit of code that solves most of their problems." - jQuery solves every problem (kidding, I upvoted)

Comment: If I downvoted every bad "Try this [code-block]" answer that I saw I would quickly lose all of my reputation

Comment: @CodeCaster We must look at different types of questions; I don't see that kind of answer much.  On clarified questions, what do you do in cases where there have been votes to close, but the question is not yet closed, and the question is then clarified?  I haven't found anything better than trolling through the thousands of items in the close vote queue looking for the question in order to vote not to close, which is way too time consuming.  Voting to close when it's no longer something that should be closed, in the hopes that it can be reopened, doesn't seem to me likely to be effective.

Comment: @andrewtweber You only have 40 votes per day (30 on answers).  So as long as you're getting 3 upvotes on answers you can use all of your answer downvotes in a day and not lose rep.  So really, if you downvote all of those kinds of answers that you see you'll just run out of votes very quickly.  People that spend a lot of time in review queues (or otherwise are heavier on the moderation side of the site) often *do* use up all of their votes very quickly.

Comment: @WarrenDew Close votes age, so if the question doesn't actually merit closure it shouldn't attract more close votes, and the existing votes will age out.

Comment: IMX, it is *very* easy for question-askers to believe that an answer is helpful to them when it actually isn't, and this *strongly* correlates with asking low quality questions in the first place. Some people don't think clearly about what they are doing; so of course if they get a piece of code and copy and paste it somewhere and the program output seems to get closer to the mark at least initially, of course that "helped".

Answer (score 17):

As has been said, a couple of things could be at work here:

- Other users also realize it is not a complete question, and are guessing the
  problem.
- The question is not as vague as you think, and other users are more perceptive
  to subtle clues in the question.

It is important to remember **the other answers are not your problem**, the
question is your problem. Essentially you are “mad” that someone might have
posted a correct answer before you, and want to take it out on them. If you
really feel that they are crap answers, then go ahead and downvote. However
remember the whole point here is to help the asker, not to beat the other
answers.

Comment: Agreed with the second bullet point especially. Sometimes when there is a question regarding a "bunch of code, library, framework, tool", it's possible that a single (sometimes cryptic) error message can indicate a common problem (e.g. library version incompatibility) that doesn't have anything in particular to do with the posted code, so it's possible to instantly reply without wasting time getting them to make an MCVE

Comment: I think you're being a little presumptuous saying that the OP wants to take it out on the FGITW posters. Sure, it can be annoying to get ninja'd while you're trying to do the right thing, but I got the impression that try-catch-finally is mostly concerned with the quality of the answers than with the rep.

Comment: The answers are *absolutely* a problem.  The whole reason that we close unclear questions is *to prevent answers to them*, and we do that because *trying to answer unclear questions is not helpful*.  It just causes lots of problems.  So yes, by all means, work on the question by voting, closing, editing, commenting, etc., but to say that there is no problem with the answers or that they aren't doing something wrong *just isn't true*.

Comment: It's not that I get mad _because someone has posted a (correct) answer before me_. I do get mad about seeing 5 new answers after 5 minutes, with constantly popping up "has been edited" while the question is still low quality. But - I have enough selfcontrol to not just take it out on FGITW posters. I either tell them they might me completely wrong or leave them alone (for a while) if the answers look competent and valuable - even though they might be still wrong in the end.

Comment: And as a sidenote and to agree to Servy: in at least 30% of the cases the TO accepts some answer leaving behind a poor or hardly to grasp question, without editing her/his post to reflect new knowledge gained in the comments section (but that's another topic - and downvoting and close-voting is the right thing to do - for me, atm.). `.oO( Note to my self: search Meta whats the consesus - whether to edit the question and add the details in my own words or just leave it as it is + close-voting ... )`

Comment: E.g., IMO, one of the "problems" Servy is referering to is, that someone stumbles over that question, carefully reads the comments, thinks "that's the same problem I have" and ... _maybe_ finds/picks the completly wrong A. Unexperienced, this one might even be happy not knowing that s/he just learned something wrong, or if experienced, s/he is quickly unhappy. Some other fellow might just get distracted by all those unclear A's. Even if they exactly reflect his problem he quickly might skipt that Q with a good 0pt answer sticking at the bottom because it doesn't look like his problem.

Comment: -1 for "the whole point is to help the asker" -- it isn't; the whole point is to **make a useful and correct question/answer pairing**, which is not quite the same thing. In particular, there's a difference in generality between the two goals, and SE is very carefully oriented *away* from ask-once-read-once-write-once scalability.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Generally, it's not a good idea to modify questions like that, unless you're moving material that the OP wrote in comments that they really ought to have edited into the question itself. Avoid paraphrasing that material, but feel free to correct grammar and spelling.

Comment: -1 (would -3 if I could). All of these have been mentioned, but they are important. (1) Other answers, which in these cases are most likely bad, *are* your - and everyone else's - problem. The site has the Q&A archive idea to it and you have tools to deal with others' answers for a reason. (2) Assuming that people are mad because someone answered before them reduces us to little children, not to talk about your suggested revenge factor. (3) You are not supposed to help an asker which doesn't ask a question according to the site's standards, it just produces "garbage".

Comment: @Servy: I've seen very clear questions that I know perfectly well what the root problem is that are closed as unclear. Sometimes what YOU think is unclear is not really unclear - it's just that you haven't personally experienced the symptoms before. Of course, questions that fail to even mention the symptoms really are unclear. But not all questions need code examples etc. Sometimes all you need is the error message.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Is it really a fallacy if it is what I observed empirically?

Answer (score 10):

I appreciate your concern for the quality of premature answers to unclear questions. However, it's not possible to evaluate those answers properly until the question is clarified. So focusing on writing comments to the OP to get that clarification is an excellent strategy. Once you have the full picture, if some of those answers *do* turn out to be wrong or misguided, feel free to comment, and if that doesn't work, to downvote. But even then, your comments should have a helpful (or at least neutral) tone, to avoid getting into disputes with other answerers.

A large proportion of unclear questions are written by first-time posters, so it's forgivable that they don't understand how to write a good Stack Overflow question, even if they have bothered to read the relevant Help pages. Many of us tend to cut them a bit of slack so that they don't have a bad first experience on SO. However, we should also endeavour to maintain good relations with the other answerers. Many first-time posters never ask another question, or at least they don't become regular members of the community. OTOH, the people who write answers *are* generally regular members of the community. Not only is it unproductive to alienate them, it can make the SO experience less enjoyable for you if you see them as adversaries that you have to fight against, rather than as team members with a somewhat different attitude that you ultimately want to co-operate with in the task of continuing to build Stack Overflow.

FWIW, when I see below-par answers I'm happy to attempt to improve those existing answers by judicious commenting, both on the question and the answers, rather than writing my own answer. I want to see good answers on Stack Overflow. Sure, it's nice to write those answers & get the points, but I also find it satisfying to help clean up other questions and other people's answers. And sometimes I write a late answer that fills in the gaps left by the other answers, or contains code that profiles the algorithms presented in those answers, so that future readers can see for themselves the merits of the various approaches.

OTOH, I've occasionally engaged in "crystal ball debugging" myself, or as BoltClock says "throwing mud at the wall and seeing what sticks", although I normally also write comments to the OP before I start working on my answer. Bear in mind that people who use this strategy are aware that it can backfire, and that you can easily end up writing an inappropriate answer if you've guessed wrong. But heh, taking risks is part of the fun. :) Of course, it's a Good Idea to check that such answers haven't been invalidated by later information, and not all FGITW answerers do that, unless prompted by a comment or downvote.

Sometimes, answers that *seem* premature aren't simply due to a wild guess: expertise in the topic and familiarity with similar questions can guide you into writing an appropriate answer to a question that other readers may consider too vague. OTOH, if the question *is* very similar to previous questions we should be looking for dupe targets, not attempting to write a new answer...

Comment: The problem is that often, one of the answers will actually help the OP, so they'll move on, happy with what they've received, and will never bother to add the required clarifications to the questions.  So no matter how much  you ask for clarification,  we're  still left with a happy OP, a rubbish question, and a bunch of dubious answers.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Yes, that is a problem. I suppose my answer should have explicitly discussed what to do when the question is never adequately clarified, but I was mostly focused on what to do while an unclear question is still active. Comments can be helpful, if not for the OP and the bad answer writers, at least they may alert future readers. And of course a liberal application of downvotes and voting to close may also be indicated. :)

Comment: (cont) Sometimes, just seeing which answer the OP accepts can make their question clearer. And when I see an OP accepting (or giving positive feedback to) a flawed or potential dangerous answer I try to alert them with a comment.

Comment: It is refreshing to see a kind, rational, and goal-oriented approach but you've lost me at *"crystal ball debugging"* -- you should use comments, not answers for that. Otherwise, I fully agree with you: unless you *know* that the answer is incorrect; you should not downvote it i.e., when in doubt you should assume good faith. It is disturbing that even some diamond moderators think otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, @J.F.Sebastian. When I engage in "crystal ball debugging" I _do_ also use comments: I don't write answers that are essentially overblown requests for clarification. But it _is_ sometimes possible to guess what the true issue is, due to personal experience with the language &/or past questions. And I did acknowledge above that it _is_ a risky strategy, but it is very nice when it pays off. :) And I keep a close watch of the question when I write answers like that in case I need to alter the answer to fit late information supplied by the OP.

Answer (score 6):

What you have highlighted in your qualm here is just a symptom of a problem.

the problem: narrowly scoped junk questions
the symptom: fast answers which address most of the underlying question.

Going after the symptom here will not address the problem. Similar to only taking pain medication to treat a broken limb, only going after answers will just make you personally feel better but make the overall situation worse.

What we need is less answers!! Right? No, that is a terrible idea.

**What we need less of is narrowly scoped junk questions!!** This, please.

If only we had a way to treat these types of questions that was easily recognizable. We used to, it was called "Too Localized" and it was great for the type of question which clearly highlighted the need for a very specific implementation of some feature. Now we have "too broad" for these apparently (that was the guidance umpteen years ago), but it doesn't properly fit for questions which are direct in their broadness. As a result, the question remains open and the answers you highlight as the problem arise.

There are often enough users viewing these questions to close them if the close reason was appropriate. However, many users will take the path of least resistance (least time) to resolving something. If they cannot immediately decide on the path to closure and can in 2 minutes write an answer and move on, they more than likely will do that. If it takes 5 minutes to figure out the reason, and 2 to answer, it is a natural response.

Take this question for example:

[How to get content of div without JavaScript script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267360/1026459)

No one closed it (yet, obviously meta will have a field day). They didn't know what to choose, because the current close options don't properly fit here without interpretation. It is clearly a "gimme teh codez" question, it highlights a scenario, what it wants, and what the output should be, but lacks any attempt at implementation or where they got stuck.

Here is another. Note that these are just from today, I didn't even look for them, *I already came across this* just in my normal browsing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267328/non-jquery-version-of-this

Another request for implementation. The user is basically asking for someone from the community to do their work for them because they are inexperienced. Literally, they said that "It's sad but I'm excellent at jquery and suck at straight up js. How do you write this WITHOUT jquery?" (it is in the revision history now)

However, at the time of writing this there is only 1 close vote! Mine. And no one else voted. 21 views, 3 different users commenting, and 1 answerer, and no one voted to close. Why? None of the reasons for closure properly matched.

### Bring back Too Localized

Not for typos or no longer reproduced. For the request for work close reason that it absolutely shined for.

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The "Too Localized" close reason was before my time here so perhaps I'm misunderstanding but "Stack Overflow is not a research assistant" and "Too Localized" seem to be about opposite problems. Too localized says the problem isn't broad enough but no research says it's too broad.

Comment: @BSMP - The shown deleted answers are just part of old guidance that used to exist in the form of "What Stack Overflow is not". It was removed a few years ago, but the guidance is still relevant in my opinion. These are not close reasons, but simply ideals that I feel have been forgotten or buried over time. The "Too Localized" close reason is simply a tool to prevent *"The SO community will not write a complete solution for you, develop a complete walkthrough of a problem, or do your background research"*. No research simply says we will not implement your features if you tried nothing.

Comment: @BSMP - Also note that Too Localized doesn't say the problem isn't broad enough, but that it doesn't apply to a broad enough audience. Which is to say that answering the question would essentially only help the OP and not help future visitors.

Comment: 7 years later: would +100 if I could. Unfortunately, it seems that the community has overwhelmingly decided that "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors" is not actually any kind of reason to close questions. Never mind that the site bills itself as a repository of questions with answers, which specifically exists for the purpose of potentially helping future visitors. "Also note that Too Localized doesn't say the problem isn't broad enough, but that it doesn't apply to a broad enough audience." Exactly. Breadth of *scope* and breadth of *application* are unrelated.

Comment: To be clear: the rationale "this question is unlikely to help any future visitors" covers more than just requests for a code dump - and I think I'm fine with that. The *best* case outcome for *typical* requests for debugging help - even after the question is edited into its best possible form, with an MRE and everything - is that people can start to notice a *pattern* in how people mess up the code or fail to debug something. At that point there's a chance for a canonical to arise from the ashes. It's relatively rare that the underlying cause is directly applicable for many people.

Answer (score 4):

If the answer actually attempts to answer the question, and clarifies what additional information has to be true, and does it well, it is an acceptable answer.

If it fails, then it isn't a good answer.

Downvote answers based on their current state, not the state it can be edited into.

I, personally, downvote answers I know to be wrong, or contain misleading/bad advice that can cause harm.  If the answer merely answers one (reasonably possible) cause for the OP's problem, I would leave it alone.  If it answers what is almost certainly the OP's problem, or does so in a great way, I might upvote.  If it answers something I judge to be highly unlikely, and/or doesn't qualify its answer with what has to be true, and/or is of poor quality for others reasons, I am likely to downvote.

Comment: I basically agree with your 1st paragraph, and such answers may be very helpful to future readers who stumble upon the question even though it may not exactly match their own problem. OTOH, if the OP _does_ eventually clarify the question with info that contradicts one or more of your assumptions, then you may need to update your answer, or risk downvotes from future readers who are unaware of the question's history.

Comment: @PM2Ring Such is the risk of answering an unclear question.

Answer (score -2):

I generally let them pass. I mean, an on topic but mediocre answer to an unclear question isn't adding much value, but neither is it doing particularly much harm.

Of course, once the question *is* clarified, and the answers are wrong, then action is more appropriate.

To this end, I find StackEye quite helpful:

https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites

You can 'watch' a question, and then see if it gets updated, you can revisit. And otherwise just forget about it.

Comment: The answers *are* causing harm though.  That the reason that we close unclear questions in the first place; we don't want people trying to answer questions that aren't clear enough to be answered.

Comment: Answering the question validates asking the question. If the question is low quality enough to be closed, it shouldn't receive an answer.

Comment: On the flip side though - if I know 'error message X probably means Y' then I feel that's a reasonable answer to give, despite it potentially being incorrect in this case - because it _is_ useful to future readers in that case.

Answer (score -16):

There is a structural problem here. My rep is less than 50, so I can't post a comment for clarification. My two choice are answer as best I can or go away and not participate in this community at all.

Comment: or, get 50 rep otherwise? you can suggest edits, post good questions, post answers to clear questions that don't need comment? That 50 rep to comment was here when I started being active as well. I got through by answering questions that didn't require clarifications.

Comment: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173)

Comment: I understand your position well enough to upvote your answer, but I would say, restrict your answers to questions which you do understand.  This can give you valuable practice in understanding questions which are not perfectly posed, so you can avoid the nasty "downvote any question that isn't perfectly designed for you" trap later on.

Comment: Sorted out that issue...