# How can I title a question about a problem that doesn't have a common description?

Tags: discussion, title, canonical

Recently I wrote a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324591/how-to-avoid-a-syntax-error-when-adding-a-variable-into-sql-query-in-php), addressing one certain problem, that causes a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that usually get wrongly closed with incorrect dupe target.

But got a message from a moderator, saying:

> I appreciate that you're trying to setup some authoritative dupe targets, but "it fails" has never been a valid problem statement here. You need to expand the description of the problem and indicate under what conditions a syntax error would be generated, and (ideally) include a textual representation of the actual error so people can find this question via Google instead of one of the countless others that does include real error messages.

But the problem is, the poor folks facing this problem are unable to formulate anything certain. The problem appears to them in various indirect consequences, so the titles are anything but an "actual error":

- [PHP Insert Into not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869513/php-insert-into-not-working)
- [Column count doesn't match value count, but there are 6 values and 6 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436553/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-but-there-are-6-values-and-6-columns)
- [Insert query not being fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337865/insert-query-not-being-fired)
- [PHP MYSQLi - Insert Hyphen into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397416/php-mysqli-insert-hyphen-into-database)
- [How to avoid mysqli_fetch_array() warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374317/how-to-avoid-mysqli-fetch-array-warning)
- [capture array values from input fields using php in mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429767/capture-array-values-from-input-fields-using-php-in-mysqli)

As you can see, there is no visible pattern in all these titles, let alone a certain error message. While the cause for all their problems is essentially the same: wrong way of constructing an SQL query in a PHP script.

So the question is: how can I title this question, to satisfy the moderator?

<sub>A short backstory behind this answer: all questions I intend to close as a dupe of this one are caused by the same problem - variables are added directly to the query, thus causing a syntax error. Simply adding quotes is not enough, as there is still a danger of either a syntax error or an SQL injection. So, if someone asks, what's wrong with a code like</sub>

```
$name = "Joe"
$sql = "INSERT INTO t VALUES($name)";
```

<sub>the proper answer would be not "just add quotes around $name" but "**use prepared statements**".</sub>

<sub>Therefore, for some time I tried to close this kind of questions as a dupe of "How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?", but got reproached, for the reason stated as "the OP didn't ask about SQL injection". There is an exemplary question of the kind - [Updating mysqli multiple columns error PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022092/updating-mysqli-multiple-columns-error-php) - which I closed for the aforementioned reason, [but it got reopened and re-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42022092/revisions) with the wrong target, so it took a moderator's intervention to get things back to sanity.</sub>

<sub>So, decided I, there should be another question that doesn't mention SQL injection, but a mere syntax error, to let all literal-kind of folks to cope with the answer.</sub>

**Update**
I've fixed the question according to the suggestions given.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> While the cause for all their problems is essentially the same: wrong way of constructing an SQL query in a PHP script.

I feel that you already have the title here.

> How to construct a SQL query correctly in a PHP script?

That's the question you intend to get answered. I would add some naive ways doing it The Wrong Way™, explaining what the problem is with those methodologies.

What you want to have at the end is:

> ## How to do this thing The Right Way™?
>
> I'm trying to do this, but if I do it like X, it has A problems, if I do Y, has B problems, if I do Z, it has C problems. Since neither X, Y, or Z seems to be robust enough, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of this one, but was afraid it doesn't directly satisfy the moderator's demand. May be just overthinked it. Think I gotta use this one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense adding some examples to the body of the question about naive solutions which have pitfalls, ie. I can do it like X, but it happens Y on certain scenario; can enrich the question.

Comment: Would it be possible to also add the error for the most common rdbms?

Comment: Hmmm. I cannot think of any other example that could be essentially different - they all boil down to the example already exists in the question. May be I am too focused on the answer, and can't concoct a good question. Surely, it would have been better to write my answer in response to a genuine question, but there is a problem - before you can write a canonical answer, there will be a couple wrong answers telling the op just to use quotes, already upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @rene That's a good idea. But just to make it straight: as it shown in the examples above, nobody actually gets any error - they just have a code that "doesn't work".

Comment: @rene that can be counterproductive in some cases, since answerers then focus on the "error" rather than in the task.

Comment: "if I do Y, has B problems" - A concrete example: "I've read [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) and added single quotes. But now when i try to insert the name O'Connor I get another error ...". That might also prevent a "wrong" duplicate close.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel a general/abstract answer on meta is more useful, since it establish hard lines. Also, using 1 instead of 3 makes it less likely to be a duplicated.

Comment: How to do this thing The Right Way™? Should go at the start. I'm here looking for that, not The Wrong Way™. Assuming the explanation of TRW (patent pending) is short I'll be able to see there is a list of TWW (patent pending) below that which I can persue if I want to, the same can't be said for a long list of TWW followed by a short TRW. :) My humble opinion of course.

Answer (score 4):

SO's QA format lends itself very readily to problems and solutions with a one-to-one relationship: one specific problem causes a program to do one specific wrong thing, so someone asks about that and gets one specific solution. For example, ["why does `if answer == 'y' or 'yes':` not work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) is a very common problem, and the basic solution is `if answer in ('y', 'yes'):`. That question has hundreds of linked posts.

The format also works fine for one-to-many situations, manifesting simply as multiple answers to one question. The above example isn't limited to a solution of `if answer in ('y', 'yes'):`, but also `if answer[0] == 'y':`, `if answer.startswith('y')`, variations with `answer.lower()`, and so on.

This paradigm, however, falls on its face when presented with a many-to-one problem. Let's imagine an esolang with a mean streak: when a program doesn't start with a line thanking the language's author, a cryptic compiler error is selected based on the length of the program. Someone attempting to write "Hello, world!" may get `error 99af: hedgehog required`, someone else attempting to write an adding machine may get `error #cthulu: soul must be purged`, and so on. This would naturally result in an SO question about `error 99af`, another about `error #cthulu`, and one more for each of the other possible error messages, the answer to all of which is "you need to read the official tutorial which clearly states in the very beginning that all programs must include a line of thanks at the top."

And that's the crux of the matter: this is a problem that never should've resulted in a question on SO, because it's a fundamental part of using that language and is covered in any number of instructional materials. Given the way many SO users insist that just because a question can be fully answered by another question's answers doesn't make it a duplicate (some people will even quibble over variable names), there can be no canonical question, and your tag will be inundated with the same issue in a million different forms, day in and day out.

Realistically, your best bet for now might be to sacrifice some realism and make an obviously phony question, like you'd see on a corporate QA site: "how do I tell all my friends about this <s>intrusive</s> wonderful service?" - "it's all taken care of; we spam everyone in your address book automatically! :)." No one improperly constructing an SQL query in a PHP script is going to ask about it in those terms. It'll sound contrived, which is okay, because it is. Your question must, in short, beg the question: the imaginary asker already knows what they're doing wrong. They're only asking to find the *right* way to do it, and they'd rather read a copy-pasted bit of a manual than read it in the actual manual. And that's your target audience: people who don't want to read the manual. Too bad for them, though, because that's what they're gonna do, whether they know it or not. Add some mention of "I'm getting all sorts of errors, like X, Y, and Z," which visitors might focus on as a match for the problems they're seeing. Then they'll know that this page might be useful, even though it looks suspiciously like documentation.

Logically, the best "canonical duplicate" would *be* documentation. I hope that one day, when Docs.SO is out of beta, we'll be able to close questions as duplicates of documentation. This will be a huge boon for everything from "how do I print" to the many forms of "how do I construct an SQL query in a PHP script."

Comment: Thank you, that's a very interesting research. But the present case has some complications (which I probably should have outlined more distinctly): this is PHP, so you can tell that there is always an extremely popular yet to the same degree wrong solution. To overturn this habit was the primary goal. PHP is known for inclining to simple yet short-sighted solutions. So here we are - ask such a question, and you'll get an  answer: "add single quotes around your variables". It's a pity but up to this day prepared statements have to fight their way against this blunt and insecure suggestion.

Comment: _"Your question must, in short, beg the question: the imaginary asker already knows what they're doing wrong"_ - that is not a prerequisite for closing a question as duplicate. What that sentence is suggesting that we should not cater to the people who want to keep this site clean and usable, but on the contrary, cater for every person who doesn't know what they're doing and who asks yet another slightly different instance of a question that's already there in thousands of variations. It is not our problem they can't put two and two together on such a fundamental level.

Comment: @CodeCaster - By that, I meant that most who ask about this don't know that the problem is due to how they construct their SQL queries. The question in a canonical self-QA would magically already know this, and just ask about the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going for a searchable title something like "#@#@ mysql does not work due to syntax error [php]". Sample (bing search) - [c# string replace does not work](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+string+replace+does+not+work).

Realistically I don't think we need new low quality *question* to serve as duplicate target in such case. It is perfectly  fine to construct reasonable question and show at least MCVE. I'd go for good descriptive, but potentially not searchable title like "Ways to construct query in MySql". If you are going for canonical answer covering not recommended ways to construct queries and reasons why that is the case would be beneficial. See [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for sample of format I suggest.

Comment: You see, there is a problem. In this particular case, nobody actually asks a certain question. They don't even sure it's an SQL related error. All they know is their code doesn't work. So I doubt that someone could make a good searchable title out of this. But nevertheless, I'll try.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the question's title, it's its body. The current body, when posted by anyone, would warrant an "off-topic: no mcve" closure, because the question lacks a reproducible case, as well as a section describing what do you expect to happen and one describing what actually happens, including the actual error message you get when executing that code with certain values.

Self-answering a question does not change the rules that apply to all questions.

Comment: Err, are you sure it's not reproducible? For me I can get the declared result (the syntax error) 10 out of 10. But I see your point for the rest: indeed, although for me it is clear that the desired behavior is a new database entry, it could be not that obvious for someone who is not that experienced in programming.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Would not you downvote such post too? There is no research or reasoning why person decided to just plop variables into the query - should be easy to fix by "I've searched https://www.bing.com/search?q=php+mysql+insert and though that I just need to replace values with variables" sentence in the post. Lack of *demonstrated* research is big problem with the post (also I think answer can get some more explanations too).

Comment: @YourCommonSense your question states "it fails", but does not show the actual error.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is a double-edged sword. If I get into too much detail, the person who clicks a link to from a dupe, wouldn't recognize their case.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok, point taken. I will add the error message.