# Should questions that contain insecure code be answered?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, security

I frequent the `encryption` tag on Stack Overflow and, as an individual, am very passionate about security best practices. I often stumble upon questions that implement incredibly insecure code, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163829/chat-box-creating-by-using-php) that contains a blatant SQL Injection vulnerability.  Often the questions I find are more technical (e.g. ECB mode in Block Ciphers, static IVs etc.) but this question is a good example.

Now, the topic of the question was not relevant to the insecurity.  BUT, the insecurity was still very much present and important.  As soon as answered (in a comment that wasn't even relevant) OP was off, even stating "[YOLO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yolo)".

I have read [Should the answer be the simplest ever possible, even at the expense of quality/security?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345664/should-the-answer-be-the-simplest-ever-possible-even-at-the-expense-of-quality) and while I agree that we are here to provide answers to questions, we are also people who have the power to promote better practices by educating new and inexperienced programmers!

If a question is asked that contains blatant security pitfalls, can we not request that the OP fix their vulnerabilities and edit their question, something like a "Blatantly insecure and/or dangerous practices" flag?

Wouldn't this be a superb way to introduce security as a fundamental pillar in application design while programmers are still learning the basics?

Comment: "he was off, even stating "YOLO"" I think that was an attempt to reply to [Yolo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2917673/yolo), the user who left [the comment that solved the asker's problem](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/73402379).

Comment: Why not? I you feel that strongly about, add note to your answer that you feel the code is insecure. You have to remember that the OP may not realize that his/her code is vulnerable and pointing it out may help them out more that what they are asking in the future. What they do with that information is up to them, but not answering IMHO will cause more harm as they may go merrily on their way not know that their code in vulnerable , when if fact they really are trying to make the most secure code as they can.

Comment: Do you expect "write code that implement asymmetric encryption" to be first homework for CS101 class?

Comment: @Alexei Not exactly, but if it were, wouldn't it be a good idea for them to learn best practice?

Comment: Personally, if I see an answer than provides an insecure method (such as one vulnerable to injection) then I comment on it and let the answerer know; probably giving a short reason  as to why it's unsafe. if they don't want to address it, or possible even ask "why does it matter", I normally downvote. Why, well the [Down Vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) page does state that *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter ..., or **an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect**.". In my opinion, an insecure answer is dangerous.