# Editing Questions and Answers to remove the Y from XY-Questions

Tags: discussion, xy-problem

There is already a similar question, regarding: [*I, myself, am the author of an XY-Question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308444/ive-asked-an-xy-question-what-should-i-do-with-it)

Now I came across a similar situation as a reviewer:

- A question, that was somewhat a XY
- One answer, that successfully identified the Y, and solved the X.
  The OP seemingly understood the problem, and accepted the answer to X.

Unlike the linked question above, there was no answer regarding Y, so the  question had an answer, but neither the title nor the content of the question was exactly, what the answer was about.

Now another person decided to step in, and edit the question in a manner, that the answer was fitting the question. As a reviewer I was unsure how to vote:

- *Approve*, for it clarified the question, in a way to devulge the true intent of the author. A conclusion drawn from the content of the accepted answer
- *Reject*, for the original intent of the author was an answer to the question asked. And uppon acceptance, the author would had the oppertunity to edit the question, but decided not to.

In this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376297/how-can-i-create-several-extjs-apps-without-duplicating-the-framework) I decided to *approve*, but I was unsure.

Comment: Without understanding the frameworks in use here: Is it fair to draw parallels between a C++ answer to a predominantly C question, or vise-versa?