# Question closed as duplicate of question closed as too localized

Tags: discussion

I just saw this question:
[How to compare three doubles and find the maximum, minimum, and the medium? (In the shortest way possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068108/how-to-compare-three-doubles-and-find-the-maximum-minimum-and-the-medium-in)

Closed as a duplicate of this question:
[Fastest way to sort 3 values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040240/the-fastest-way-to-sort-3-values-java)

That makes sense, the duplicate is clear.

However the second question has itself been closed as "Too Localized".

That made me think however, surely if another question is a duplicate of it then it cannot be "Too Localized" as by definition it would help someone else (the person asking the dupe).

So should I do a reopen vote on the original even though it was closed three years ago?

Comment: renominate for opening, makes sense

Comment: "Too localized" doesn't exist as a close reason anymore anyway. This isn't to say that I think all of those question should be automatically re-opened, just that it doesn't seem unreasonable to consider it if there's no other problems with it.

Comment: They are homework questions.  This is what "too localized" means, it only helps students completing their assignment.  The answers do absolutely squat to actually help them think like a programmer.  We don't do a very good job promoting our profession, nobody will ever give it the same kind of status as a doctor or lawyer when we intentionally help students to not think for themselves.

Comment: crap is crap regardless of the reason for the crap, @HansPassant is right. Neither of these questions or any of the answers help the profession and promote the community in a poor way. Making the community less educated. What happens when SO when the current generation of contributors fade out and these useless question people are the only ones left?

Comment: *"Neither of these questions or any of the answers help the profession and promote the community in a poor way"* however none of that has anything to do with the question being on topic. I won't however disagree that it is a low quality question.

Comment: Promoting students to ask *good questions* is probably not a bad thing.  It depends if they attempted anything at all.  Sometimes they actually show quite a bit of intelligence and wonder about something beyond the curriculum.  But those are rare...

Answer (score 3):

Apply a test of whether the question should be closed *at all*, rather than just whether the question should be closed *for that reason*. Reopening an old question in the belief that it is a good question that might get more answers and/or votes (perhaps by showing up in google searches) is a good thing to do. Reopening an old question so that it can be quickly closed again for a different reason is just noise.

[Fastest way to sort 3 values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040240/fastest-way-to-sort-3-values-in-java) fairly clearly *shouldn't* be kept open - it's a "do my homework for me" question. As of this post, it has been reopened but has three votes to re-close as off topic with the reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: It's closed now.

Comment: [Closing *"do my homework for me"* questions does not work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308842/4279) and it is harmful: If I have the same question; I don't care whether someone had this question as a homework. If I landed on SO after a web-search; I want to see a solution to my specific problem (90+% visits). If the question is open then a newer/more up-to-date solutions might be added. If the question is useful then it remains useful whether or not it is a homework.