# On the criteria for "too broad" questions?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

A couple of months ago, I started contributing to Stack Overflow, and since then I've been trying to understand issues such as "review" tasks. Although most issues seem pretty clear, others seem to live in some sort of limbo.

One example is the "too broad" definition:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
> too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
> or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

In theory, this is a good enough explanation for a number of questions:

- How to make a spreadsheet software?
- How to design an architecture for my game?
- How to juggle 3 oranges while peeling a banana? (I'm actually curious about this one so feel free to answer)

These are all examples that fit perfectly the definition and are typically put on hold as a result. But recently I've been seeing quite a few questions that do not seem to be "too broad" at all (although likely poorly asked). Such is the case for:

- [How can I make a figure that has two x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245384/how-can-i-make-a-figure-that-has-two-x-axis/37251963#37251963)
- [Interpolate Z values in a 3D surface, starting from an irregular set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031338/interpolate-z-values-in-a-3d-surface-starting-from-an-irregular-set-of-points/36037288#36037288)

These questions actually visually identify the problem and are generally specific about the expected outcome. In the first question, the user requests a plot with two axis that looks like the image it linked (from Excel) but made in Python, specifically with matplotlib. The second user wanted an alternative to `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` (interpolation function in Python) that apparently was giving strange results for its case study (and he showed the pictures for it).

Arguably, we can consider those questions as being of poor quality (or at least expressed badly). But take that first example and compare it directly with this:

- [How to Plot ROC curve in pyhton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110924/how-to-plot-roc-curve-in-pyhton/37113381#37113381)
- [Converting 1D radial profil to 2D image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501494/converting-1d-radial-profil-to-2d-image/36502578#36502578)
- [Visualization of wavelets coefficients for different deconstruction levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756500/visualization-of-wavelets-coefficients-for-different-deconstruction-levels/36765378#36765378)
- [How to plot multi-objectives pareto frontier with DEAP in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000488/how-to-plot-multi-objectives-pareto-frontier-with-deap-in-python/37001414#37001414)

  and let me give you one even more amazing:
- [How to plot an amoeba like figure on matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123322/how-to-plot-an-amoeba-like-figure-on-matplotlib/37149163#37149163)

It's a short sample from my own experience, but it feels like, by comparison, closing the first examples are a result of [primarily opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

I don't have enough reputation to vote to close yet, but I would guess that there might be some bias in the system.

**When a user votes for close, do they know if other people close voted too?** Can they see what categories the votes were cast in?

**Is it likely that some questions might be being closed as "too broad" because they are actually of "too poor quality"?** (...not sure if latter exists as a category in SO)

**Are the questions I gave as examples not useful for SO?** (personally I think they are useful; in the past I found some gems of answers in similar examples)

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I'm not questioning the term "too broad", I'm questioning its criteria, particularly how it seems to be used (or interpreted) in SO.

Comment: Yes, when you cast a close-vote, you see previous ones.

Comment: And, looking into the links you give that were too broad, but you question it: the close reason might be poor here...but the fact that the "two x axis" is litteraly a request for someone else to do their work... I see little value in keeping that question around.

Comment: @Patrice True, but the justification should be entirely different. Also I'm not too sure about the value of keeping or not keeping the question. Some people actually have difficulty into expressing themselves, or are used to do things as they did on other sites. We are kind of missing the pedagogical lesson here.

Comment: @armatia we were never meant as pedagogs on stack (wow i know that's a word in French... Guess it's one in English too?). Anyway. The intent of stack is to provide a high repository of programming knowledge. That "two X-axis" questionis asked in a way that makes it unlikely anyone will ever search for it... So the benefit to the site is minimal

Comment: @Patrice I think it's naturally implied in Q&A site. And there are plenty of clues for the pedagogical value of an answer, including a low quality flag. In review its common to appear answers with a solution but without any sort of explanation. Those appear there because someone flagged them as low quality. NOTE: My french ain't that good yet but the word does seem to exist in English, although "educator" might be more appropriate.

Comment: My favorite quote: [We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. If this means **aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it**. Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104)

Comment: @Braiam That seems a bit extreme. I could say questions are just as essential. But the thing is: I don't think its helpful to take a moralist approach on these issues. I answered all of the examples provided in the question and done so willingly. Didn't feel unhappy about it too. I think the questions are relevant, but poorly written (which is a different problem altogether from my point of view).

Comment: The thing is... how long are you willing to keep answering them? And, how about your peers that are tired of seeing the same kind of uninteresting questions?

Comment: @Braiam That first question is valid for anyone one of us, regarding any type of question, good or bad. The same for the second. Just because some don't want to answer does not mean others aren't willing. Besides I actually found some of those questions interesting and gave the answer I would have liked to get If I were the one doing the questioning. But this could be helping even for those, hmm... less eloquent. There might be more adequate ways of educating users to write better their questions. The question is if there is any willingness for the community to allow it?

Comment: @armatita the problem here is a simple one of scale. With the amount of new and crappy questions a day, it is impossible to hold each new user by the hand.    And i disagree about your statement on the usefulness of these questions (in the SO context at least). This site was always meant for the NEXT visitor. If a question lacks so much no one else will see it, it's useless as per Stack's goal.

Comment: @Patrice The amount of questions SO can deal with will always depend on the number of people willing to answer those questions. Perhaps more efforts should be done to prevent new questions from being crappy. I do think those questions might be useful for the next visitor. If it has a clear purpose, and a solution, why not? In the first example I presented, I can't believe that guy is the only one that wants to be able to do a stacked bar plot with two x-axis in matplotlib. And I doubt that other people seeing the solution won't want to adapt to whatever their problem might be.

Comment: @armatita here you hit it on the head I'd say "adapt to whatever their problem might be". People don't do that, end up not researching, and post virtual duplicates (kinda besides the point though). In any case, I am ALL for making questions better. I am actually one of the usual meta lurkers who will give it to new users that the site IS harsh and hard to deal with a time. There are reasons for it, and justifications for them, but still, doesn't change that fact. I am still not 100% sure how to prevent questions from being crappy when the new user base feels that entitled.

Comment: Heck, I've seen a new user (I'm not even paraphrasing here) "I don't give a shit about your quality and rules. Just get me my fucking answer". Kinda hard to make THESE users right proper questions...

Comment: @Patrice True, some people can be difficult but I don't think it's the majority. I haven't gave much though about how to teach users write better questions but there could be a possibility to have some kind of grade system (whose results would only be visible to OP and moderation) stating quality by category (Example: Writing quality-> 4 ; Research->2 ; Initiative->0; I'm making this up for exemplification purposes). SO already gives badges for all kinds of stuff, why not use that system to stimulate better questions (Novelist badge: get grade 5 in writing for at least 10 questions).

Comment: @armatita not a bad idea, per se. Never going to be scalable to Stack's level... who assigns these grades? (and honestly, normally people start with a lot of enthusiasm towards the community and burn out quick... I know I have :( )

Comment: @Patrice Everyone! It could be the same system as up votes and down votes. The difference would be only the OP would know the results (to avoid humiliating experiences, it's supposed to educate after all). Or if any result would be shown it should be only positive stuff (This question has the: Writing medal (average writing quality above 4), Initiative medal (minimal verifiable example well present with average quality above 4), and so on). I'm making this up as I write because its a comment. I would need to think better about it but I'm confident solutions could be found.

Comment: @armatita but we have way too many questions to be able to do this.... how do you deal with questions who get so little traffic there is no stats on? How does this relate to the ban? And again... scalability is a BIG concern here.... We already have problems with it with just up and downvotes (and close/edits). Adding categories to vote on, which will end up being EXTREMELY subjective, can only mean more "work" per post, and we're already lacking in that

Comment: @Patrice But you are already allocating the time for close votes an such. Why couldn't this be just like any other review task. The scale is the same it already has, it's the purpose that changes. But perhaps you are right. As I said I haven't though this trough so there might be holes I'm not considering. It was just an idea out of the box.

Comment: @armatita oh for sure, it would just be one of many review queues. The close vote review queue is currently at a couple of Ks entries that need review. That's the issue here. Not saying it's not a good idea (honestly, it is potentially one of the best ideas for something like this I've read). The issue is and remains "how do you deal with 8000 new questions a day, about 6000 of them being bad, and out of those 6000 bad ones, only 1000 have OPs willing to improve, when there is less involved members on the site". Seriously though, this isn't a terrible idea, as they go.

Comment: @Patrice It's probable that it wouldn't have a good reception, likely for the reasons you pointed out. Perhaps once I get a better grasp of the SO universe I'll come up with something more solid. In any case, thanks for the feedback. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can see close votes (I got the power yesterday!). Here, take a look:

[image: Seeing Close Votes]

Anyway, the close reason chosen is the one that a majority of people chose (in a tie, the last vote wins). When a question is particularly low quality, sometimes it's hard to pick the *right* reason. There's just so much that's wrong sometimes...

"Too Broad" is the go to option for many people when the question is asking for people to write the entire program that they have for homework (for a example that you will see time and time again). While it's obvious that they would accept the first thing that works, there are a lot of different ways to accomplish these types of things.

---

I am also [starting to get the feeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307134/lossless-compression-algorithm-with-small-footprint-and-good-compression-ratio?noredirect=1#comment62136594_37307134) that many people don't care about closing things with the right reason.

But your examples are certainly not the worst uses of the close reason I've seen.

Comment: Congratulations; Thank you (including the grammar corrections); and good example. Well the examples are not great but I doubt they are useless for future users. It seems there are a lot questions being closed because they are badly formulated. The reasons could be plenty, including non-English speakers trying to do their best.  I think its an issue that deserves some further consideration.

Comment: @armatita I do a lot of editing, especially on SO, to help the questions posted by non-native speakers. (Unfortunately, I am convinced that a number of the things I fix were posted by native speakers that were just lazy.) Of course, everyone should provide some code in their question, which might have been able to save a number of these questions from closure.

Answer (score 3):

> When a user votes for close, do they know if other people close voted too? Can they see what categories the votes were cast in?

Yes and yes.

> Is it likely that some questions might be being closed as "too broad" because they are actually of "too poor quality"?

It is a possibility, of course, but more than likely you are missing a little bit of history behind "too broad".

> Are the questions I gave as examples not useful for SO?

No, they are not useful.

---

It can be difficult to follow the half a decades worth of history behind close reasons if you have just arrived at Stack Overflow. A long time ago, these questions would have been closed as "Too Localized" under the clause that the solution was unlikely to help anyone except the OP. However, that reason was removed from the list of close reasons because it was being misused.

[Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/178816)

There was a decent amount of backlash.

[Responding to your "too localized" concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185102/178816)

During the removal, the guidance was to use "Too Broad" to close questions which were basically requirement statements. In my opinion, these are "Job Shop" questions, and are essentially just requests for the community to do free work.

I feel like the "Too Broad" close reason is the correct reason for these, and I think it is a shared opinion in the community. Asking a question which simply states "do this for me, here is what it should look like" is not a question at all, it is a demand or request.

That said, I agree that the reason could be a little more explicit and have actually had that discussion already as well.

[Make it easier to close job shop "gimme teh codez" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459)

> Your question would receive too many long answers, would require users to create all the code, or write a tutorial. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

The wording isn't perfect, but hopefully the idea is conveyed.

Comment: It seems a valid choice. And it looks I have some reading to do. In any case I do not feel those questions to be useless to SO users (this is independent of the good or bad intentions of the OP). They can convey good quality knowledge in terms of recipes, ideas, or suggestions. The point I'm trying to expose here is that, by following that criteria, all of the examples in the question should be closed. And I doubt that would be helpful to anyone.

Comment: @armatita - Are you familiar with the meta effect? It is possible given time those posts will be closed, as the only person they are likely to help is the OP going forward. Stack Overflow is not a code for free service, the last thing needed is to have companies plan on having whole applications written piecewise here by simply asking questions; which is why these types of questions are closed. And to note, in some cases this has already been attempted.

Comment: I do now. Thanks for pointing it out. I've put those examples there because they are from my own experience and the criteria for closing seemed almost arbitrary (or at least unclear). Although the site isn't meant as a consultancy service it will always depend on the personality of the plenty participating. I do see your point but I wonder if its not at risk of falling into some very harsh rules for newcomers. This might be a product of scale, rather than logic. I have no numbers but SO seems to be less tolerant than other smaller, more recent, communities.