# What to do with answers addressing an old version of a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

I have a question about this question: *[Waiting different time between function calls when using setInterval in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412930/waiting-different-time-between-function-calls-when-using-setinterval-in-javascri/33414410)*

At first, it was quite unclear what the OP actually wanted to do. Despite
this, it quickly received two answers that addressed two reasonable, although incorrect, interpretations of the question.

After some discussion in comments (now deleted) and chat, I managed to figure out what the real question was and together with the OP edit the question into what I think is a reasonable shape. I have also answered it, and my answer was accepted.

Now I wonder what to do about the two old answers, which do not address the current version of the question, but rather an old vague version of it. I see a number of possibilities:

1. Do nothing?
2. Downvote answers? Feels wrong — after all the persons who posted the answer did nothing wrong and does not deserve to lose any reputation.
3. Flag answers? I don't find any flag that would fit.
4. Leave polite comments on the answers informing the authors about the situation and suggesting that they delete (or update) their answers. Could perhaps be interpreted as a bit rude, as me trying to highlight my own answer at their expense?
5. What I did was wrong and the question should not have been clarified after it had already received answers since it invalidated those answers?
6. Something else?

Comment: I'd opt for 4., you can avoid rudeness by explaining what actually happened.

Answer (score 21):

> Do nothing?

You have incorrect, and therefore unhelpful, answers, so no, you shouldn't do nothing.

> Downvote answers? Feels wrong - after all the persons who posted the answer did nothing wrong and does not deserve to lose any reputation.

They *absolutely* did something wrong.  They answered an unclear question rather than waiting for the author to clarify it.  As a result, they posted an unhelpful answer, and the appropriate way to indicate that is to downvote it.

> Flag answers? I don't find any flag that would fit.

You should not flag answers for being wrong, no.

> Leave a polite comments to the answers informing the authors about the situation and suggesting that they delete (or update) their answers. Could perhaps be interpreted as a bit rude, as me trying to highlight my own answer at their expense?

You're welcome to post such a comment if you want.

> What I did was wrong and the question should not have been clarified after it had already recieved answers since it invalidated those answers?

No, the people that posted the answers were the one that did something wrong.

> Something else?

Nope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Does this apply even if the authors of the answers made the *most* plausible, but not *only* plausible interpretation of the question? And the correct interpretation would have been very hard to guess from the original version of the question?

Comment: @Anders Yes.  They were wrong, and as such the answer isn't helpful.  The votes should reflect that.  The fact that it was hard to guess what the right answer was to the unclear question *is exactly why they shouldn't have answered it in the first place*.

Comment: @Anders: As I mentioned in [this recent Meta SO answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308322/4014959), people who write speculative answers to unclear questions (generally) realise that they're engaging in risky behaviour. They may score points if they've guessed right, but OTOH they _need_ to keep close watch for changes in the question if they don't want to risk downvotes. And if the OP comes back & changes the question 12 hours later when you're not online, well, them's the breaks. :)

Comment: But note - that's _not_ the same as a chameleon question where they ask one thing (clearly) but then amend the question later to ask something different.

Comment: I agree with this. I'd leave a comment to indicate why you're downvoting, and keep an eye on the answer for a bit to see if they fix it (at which point you can remove your downvote and maybe even upvote).  However, I *would* downvote it (not because they're wrong but simply because they're not helpful anymore). Worrying about the effect on the answerer doesn't come into it for me, you vote the answer, not the person.

Answer (score 13):

If the edits just clarified the question, instead of replacing it, then editing instead of posting a new question was the right thing.

If the other answers guessed wrong, you might comment so they have a chance to withdraw or correct their answer (at your discretion, if you think that will help), and also downvote as the answer evidently is *not useful*.
If one plays fast and loose, one is likely to get caught sometimes.

If the answer is edited, you can retract your vote and even upvote.
If it is deleted, any reputation-changes are reversed.
If neither happens, you at least signalled to everyone else what that answer is worth.

Answer (score 9):

> At first, it was quite unclear what the OP actually wanted to do. Despite this it quickly received two answers that addressed two reasonable, although incorrect, interpretations of the question.

Those people should not have answered at all, which makes the following easier to stomach.

> Now I [wonder] what to do about the two old answers, who does not address the current version of the question but an old vague version of it.

The question should not have fundamentally changed, but the practical reality is that this happens from time to time. However, this does not change anything about the present quality/relevance of the answers, so you should treat them as you would if the question had *never* been an "older version":

**Downvote!**

If you feel the authors "don't deserve" to lose reputation, well that's sweet and all, but *that is not a proper factor when deciding how to vote on a post*. When you vote, you vote on the quality and relevance of a post. The rep gained/lost as a result should be none of your concern. Abstract it away.

In this case it's actually quite convenient that the author will be punished for jumping in with a guess answer to a poorly-defined question. They'll think twice before grabbing at rep again.

They may offset the rep loss by deleting the now-broken answer (which will also help to keep the page clean); if they do this enough, though, they'll get an automated answering ban. Again, if such behaviour continues, that result is *a good thing*.