# I'm new to Stack Overflow; what are some things I should do, and what things will I likely want to do that I shouldn't?

Tags: discussion, new-users, etiquette

I've noticed that not every question is supposed to be answered. My immediate tendency upon joining was to sit there and refresh the questions section hoping to find one that I could answer, only to end up losing points because the question I did answer was a poorly written question.

My goal is to become an active member of Stack Overflow who makes helpful contributions. What are important things that I should know in order to successfully do that?

Comment: Have you read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) yet?

Comment: You can add favorite teams so you'll see more questions that you be able to answer. Ignore poorly written question - Answering those will more likely get you downvoted, even if your answer is correct, simply because SO community hates those lazy, low-quality type of questions

Comment: I did the SO tour, and and I know I have glanced at it in the past! I'll have to re-read it, but there are a couple of things I didn't really see there, although I may have simply missed them! An example of something that I didn't find much info on was what questions to answer, rather than just how to answer them. It's just a bit nerve wracking posting on SO because as a noob, it's really easy to ask a horrible question that gets downvoted to hell, but it's actually kind of hard to ask a good question, and it's really hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Similar and probably useful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow (This is more about how to earn rep than identifying useful content)

Comment: @Tristen Usually you always tell whether the op made a proper research before asking - if it's a common issue like a typical error that can easily be Googled, or if it's missing important details (Like the actual code) then you should not answer it. But if it's a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that meets SO standards then by all means answer it - **Explain what's wrong** with the current code, provide an alternative solution and **explain what it does**. Try writing answers that will help not only the OP, but other users with similar issues

Comment: All the help center links you want for identifying a good question are at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: When you're new, it may be useful not to answer questions that are brand new. Although some are missed, a lot of off-topic questions are closed quickly, so if a question is a day old, it is less likely to be off-topic.

Comment: This seems like it should be part of the FAQ.

Comment: @BSMP This is just a duplicate of the FAQ.  If you want to know what you should and shouldn't do on the site, you read the FAQ.  Trying to fit the entire FAQ into a single question doesn't improve it.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

#### To Start

First and most importantly, I highly suggest reading through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). This will give you most of what you need to know about the basics of the sites.

This will also give you resources and tips for writing good questions and answers, and you'll have some background as to *which* questions should be closed rather than answered.

After this, you can go and start trying to answer and ask questions, or you can opt to do more research. Of course, you can opt to do both.

#### More Research

If you decide to do more to learn about the culture, I would start with the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts here on Meta Stack Overflow (MSO). Those have evolved over time and will help you learn even more about the current state of things. These posts are curated by the community, so they can generally be updated faster and more easily than the help center.

After this, consider browsing MSO. I recommend the "Active" and "Frequent" tabs. The latter gives you the posts that have been linked to the most often, so they tend to be posts that are either often referenced or often re-asked.

Once you've done this, you should have a pretty decent feel for how the community thinks and acts about various topics. You'll pick up tips and guidelines that you wouldn't have found in the help center.

#### Posting

When you return to posting, I suggest you take feedback to heart. If you don't agree with a change, ask for clarification why you would need to make it.

Remember that if a discussion starts to get heated, it's always best to walk away. Flag any inappropriate or off-topic comments, but it's always best not to be involved.

On that note, also remember that you don't have to be perfect. The above paragraph is easier said than done, and even a careful user will not always be able to hold their tongue. *This works both ways.* Other users who are normally calm and collected may snap if you ask questions and they're having a bad day. Just try your best, and remember that others' bad behavior is no reason for you to misbehave.

#### Picking Questions to Answer

1. **Don't be in a hurry.**

   If you find yourself constantly hitting refresh looking for a question, one suggestion is to start in the list at between 6 hours to a day old. Then go backwards from there looking for a question to work on.  Questions that are old, that shouldn't be answered, have likely already been downvoted. So that can help you filter what to answer until you get more experience.
2. **Pick questions that will stretch you.**

   In general you will not get as much reputation on older unanswered questions, but you can get practice answering questions, and since there is little rush to answer, you can pick a question that will take more research, and you have the time to go figure it out.

   Net result, you learn something, and someone gets a question answered that might have just languished.
3. **Don't answer poor-quality questions.**

   Before answering a question, do a quick search on the title of the question, and then using other related search terms that might turn up an identical question. Too often, a question is asked which has already been answered before, sometimes *many* times before. Vote to close or flag such questions using the "duplicate" reason, rather than posting yet another answer.

   Make sure the question is clear and unambiguous, concisely stated, and contains a useful code example (most questions really should have a full [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but at the very least there needs to be enough code to completely illustrate the question). If possible, edit the question to improve it so that it meets those standards. If not possible, downvote.

   It's always helpful to post a comment under the question to encourage the question's author to improve their question, explaining precisely how they can do so. Sometimes, this can be all it takes to help a question poster get their question on the right track.

   If this doesn't help, then you can flag posts that need to be closed, an ability you unlock at 15 rep. This is a great way for low rep users to help get questions closed. For example, if you find a duplicate, even if you can't vote to close you can still *flag* the question. This will leave a comment linking to the other post and will put the question in the Close Vote review queue for others to see.

   If you don't have enough reputation to post a comment, focus on other activities that will garner you the necessary reputation points (for example, answering other, high quality questions or editing posts that could use some help).

#### Things To Avoid

Here are a few things that could quickly get you into hot water, but are common mistakes:

1. **Your posts are community curated, so please do not undo useful edits.**

   You may already be familiar with this. You would be surprised how many users get angry when their posts are edited!

   If you don't agree with an edit, you can undo it. Keep in mind, however, that it's frowned upon to "vandalize" your posts, or make them worse. If someone edits your post to correct grammar or help format your post to be more readable, please don't undo that edit.

   However, if someone edits your post to completely change the wording, change your coding style, or otherwise change what your answer says, you are more than welcome to undo that edit.
2. **Do not, under any circumstances, post a comment in the answer box.**

   This may seem self-explanatory, but a lot of people do this. Writing any form of "I don't have the rep to comment, so I'm posting this as an answer" does not excuse this act.

   Long story short, just don't do it. If you don't have the rep to do something, then don't try to workaround it please. Your post will be deleted at best, and you'll have angry users to deal with at worst.
3. **Don't post just a link to answer a question.**

   Stack Overflow is meant to be a high-quality repository of problems and their solutions. To accomplish this, we like to have posts be as self-contained as possible.

   If you link to a tool/plugin/library that will solve a user's problems, great! But please, explain why or how that tool helps. Even better, show *how,* if possible, to use the tool to solve the problem. A brief code snippet showing how to use a library, for example, or the function the user needs to call and how to incorporate it takes a low-quality or average answer and helps make it a good answer.

   If you're linking instead to documentation or a blog or such to help explain something, quote the relevant part of the page and explain in your own words how it answers the question. If the relevant part is the entire linked page, summarize it as best you can and explain how this helps.

   This actually leads into...
4. **Don't plagiarize.**

   To meet the last point, you might decide to just copy and paste large parts of pages to your answer. Don't do this! If the section you're copying is large, try to summarize. *Always* provide a source to the page and give proper attribution. Put anything you quote this way in a blockquote. Hit the quote key on the toolbar, or insert a `>` before each line of the quote.

   If you are quoting another answer on Stack Overflow, check if the questions might be a duplicate of each other. If yes, [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) one of them as duplicate of the better one.
5. **Don't post images of code or text.**

   This might also seem like a no-brainer, but a lot of people do this.

   Posting images of your code, error message, console output, etc. make it harder for your post to be found through searches, or for readers to paste what you have presented into their editor window. It also makes things much more difficult for users with screen readers.

   If you can't copy and paste, it's far more preferable to hand-type anything you can. If an error is long, try to post the most relevant part of the error and not the whole thing.
6. **Don't try to be the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/293308)**

   A well thought-out answer that takes longer to write is better than "Try this" followed by a code dump. Posting an incomplete answer so it gets seen first can lead to downvotes from users who don't find it useful, even if you intend to improve it with later edits.

---

<sub>If I have missed anything in the above, please feel free to edit it in and make this a more complete source for the OP and future users.</sub>

Comment: [This is relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308302/how-to-deal-with-unclear-questions-and-their-lightning-fast-fastest-gun-in-the) - Don't answer as fast as you can, make sure you understand what the OP is asking

Comment: So many _don't_...

Comment: Has it been considered to have some sort of delay to mitigate the FGITW problem?   Maybe something like the "Post Your Answer" button just says "Hold on there Tex!" instead of submitting the answer if the question is less than N (N=5? 10? ...?) minutes old?

Comment: Great work, Kendra - excellent list.

Comment: Also do not hurry to close a question right away after it is asked. Try to guide the OP through comments. When the OP is not collaborative as to improve his question after a reasonable time, vote or flag to close it.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ This is subjective, I always downvote and VTC low quality questions and I don't care how the OP feel about it. I _might_ instruct them in the comments if i'm in a good mood. They have all the information available before they post a question and also after their question is closed. If they improve the question before I closed the tab then I'll happily retract my vote and remove my downvote (And perhaps upvote if it's now a _very_ good question)

Comment: How about dont post a question that can be found in an online search?  Seems to be the #1 people here pile on someone to vote them down in large numbers.  I rarely ask questions here due to the negative response.  I simply couldnt find a good explanation online yet people hammered a few of my posts to death with the only response is it was able to be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Take the time to make sure you're answering the person's question. I know this sounds a bit ridiculous, but usually a downvote happens because the information is obscured, incomplete or the original question was answered hurriedly and thus missed the mark.

Doing research for the good of the person goes a long way around here, and usually you are thanked for it by having reputation growth. Of course, don't forget the help center.

One of the worst kinds of feedback are biased entries such as, "I can't believe you are using Windows for that" or "Linux isn't really made for that". This is just awkward, as it doesn't help the person AT ALL and is usually just someone trying to earn a badge in a hurry. It also shows the person as being opinionated, but not helpful. Please avoid doing this, as I have seen it a few times, and it always gets removed.