# Building Rep and Etiquette

Tags: discussion, reputation, comment-votes

I have pretty recently begun to try to be active on Stack Overflow/Exchange and am still trying to get enough rep to comment on questions. Sometimes it is difficult to answer questions that don't include enough information and the answer doesn't seem like the best place to ask for clarification.

I have answered on a couple of questions where the OP doesn't upvote or select an answer. Is it bad form to comment on my own answer asking the OP to select an answer (but not necessarily mine)?

Also, I recently answered a question that was worded somewhat unclearly. Later the OP commented on my answer stating that I did not address their question but that he updated his question to be more clear. In such a case should I delete my answer or would it be best to leave it for historical purposes?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: You can easily achieve 50 points by editing Q&A's. Just make sure you read the [help] regarding what constitutes a good edit.

Comment: Also related: [I'm new to Stack Overflow; what are some things I should do, and what things will I likely want to do, that I shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil) (**Things To Avoid** #2)

Comment: Another route to 50 rep is to head off to another site in the Stack Exchange network and earn 200 rep there, you'll get an Association Bonus of +100 rep on every other network site you're a part of.  Other topics might be more suited to you (for instance, I have more rep in World Building than I do here on SO!)

Comment: Ok, I'm probably breaking another rule because this has probably been asked on one of the links posted here but, given that this is a duplicate post, should I delete it or does it get deleted automatically at some point?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  This has more than one answer to it so it's an alright signpost.