# Stress Problems With Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, user-experience

I know this might sound crazy, but users like me can get stressed when asking, answering, or even commenting questions. I always ask myself: "Will I lose reputation, will it get down-voted or deleted?" It's always annoying me, and every time when I log in to Stack Overflow, I feel afraid by looking at my recent notifications.

Can someone give me tips on how to make good answers and questions and how to relieve stress?

Comment: It's a good thing. It makes you that little bit more likely to double check your question/answer/comment before posting it. When you open your mouth in the real world, your real world reputation is at stake, why should this be any different?

Comment: There are a number of questions on Meta Stack Overflow about the topic of starting off on SO you may find helpful, for instance [I'm new to Stack Overflow; what are some things I should do, and what things will I likely want to do that I shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/215552) and [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/215552). Apart from that, the [ask] page has a number of tips, and links to other resources. For answering, there's [answer].

Comment: @TinyGiant: Someone who experiences conscious stress whenever they talk in the real world is suffering from social anxiety. That's not normal, and it's not healthy. If SO is exacerbating similar symptoms, that's not normal, and that's not healthy.

Comment: @Nathan That depends on how you define stress. If you're talking about biting your nails and rocking back and forth in a corner because you just can't decide whether to wear the brown pants or the black pants, then yeah that's a bad thing. But not all stress is felt that extremely, and most of us encounter stress in one form or another every day. If we didn't, we wouldn't care about anything and nothing would ever get done. Besides, if just interacting with others stresses you out to the point that it becomes unhealthy, there isn't really anything Stack Overflow can to help that.

Comment: This is what beer is for..

Comment: @TinyGiant: If someone thinks to themselves "will I look silly, will they think I'm dumb because I said that" every time they open their mouth… that's social anxiety.

Comment: @Nathan When I'm about to open my mouth I usually ask myself how what I'm about to say will affect others and their opinions of me. I wouldn't say that means I have social anxiety, I would say it means I consider what I say before saying it.

Comment: It's a lot harder to get downvoted on answers than it is to get downvoted on questions. Assuming the answer is correct and actually an answer.

Comment: See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: "or even commenting questions" - you... don't have enough reputation to leave comments? I hope you're not trying to post comments as answers. Or do you mean comments on your *own* questions? Also, people can't downvote comments, and even having your comments deleted by mods tend not to have much consequence (unless you're leaving highly objectionable comments, e.g. very rude ones) so that's fairly low risk.

Comment: In the past week I started to write a couple questions. While posting I realized I needed a better MCVE, I needed to look carefully at the documentation etc. in the end I did not post any question *because this process ended up with finding the solution by myself*. Even if it doesn't being stressed to properly research before asking will yield a much better & answerable question that shouldn't result in anything bad.

Comment: I eat apples and swear a lot while asking/answering. In fairness, I actually do that all the time. Might help you too though.

Comment: @MartinJames ...I'm pretty sure that using beer for this is one of the ways people become alcoholics...

Comment: Now you know why downvotes don't give you a notification, only upvotes ;)

Comment: Every time I post a new question I say to myself: "Let the downvoting begin!".

Comment: @MichaelPotter you could write a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) query to select all posts authored by Jon Skeet, then look at the votes table for each post to get the downvotes.

Comment: Hello Devealte. Sorry Stack Overflow makes you so stressed. I disagree with most people here - **it is not a good thing you feel bad using Stack Overflow**. We should have better tools at our disposal that allow us to organize the site and introduce new users to how it works without hurting people in the process or make them feel "punished" - which may be unavoidable, but in my opinion happens too often. As you probably know - [they're working on it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), and I for one hope they succeed.

Comment: @Kobi even though you're not wrong, over-sensitivity is also a common theme in this day and age. Don't feel *too* sorry for just everyone that gets upset.

Comment: Posting a question on the meta site is the most stressful for me, you could walk away for 5 minutes after posting and come back to a -25 voted down question! :)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The site is *designed* to induce a certain amount of stress.  That stress/anxiety is meant to nudge you towards being careful and considerate about what you do on the site.

From Jeff Atwood, one of Stack Overflow's co-founders:

> I've heard people describe the process of asking a question on Stack Overflow as anxiety inducing. To me, posting on Stack Overflow is supposed to involve a healthy kind of minor "let me be sure to show off my best work" anxiety:
>
> - the anxiety of giving a presentation to your fellow peers
> - the anxiety of doing well on a test
> - the anxiety of showing up to a new job with talented coworkers you admire
> - the anxiety of attending your first day at school with other students at your level
>
> I imagine systems where there is zero anxiety involved and I can only think of jobs where I had long since stopped caring about the work and thus had no anxiety about whether I even showed for work on any given day. How can that be good? Let's just say I'm not a fan of zero-anxiety systems.

Source: [What does Stack Overflow want to be when it grows up?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)

So there is probably no way to completely avoid stress when participating on Stack Overflow.

Definitely check out the 'How do I...' links [that Rubén posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375705/242). They have great info that will help you to get better at asking and answering.

There is [lots of discussion](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) about improving the experience for new users. But how to treat new users in a civil manner while encouraging/teaching them to do the right thing, and simultaneously ensuring their actions don't harm/devalue the site, is proving to be a [very tough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who) and [contentious problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t).

Answer (score 31):

This is called [Loss Aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion):

> In cognitive psychology and decision theory, loss aversion refers to people's tendency to prefer avoiding losses to acquiring equivalent gains: it is better to not lose $5 than to find $5.

This is built into the system in order to encourage behaviors that are deemed "good" and to discourage behaviors that are deemed "bad". If you do something and lose money because of how you did it, you would avoid doing it that way the next time around.

- If you ask a question without including the information that is necessary for us to answer the question, you're likely to lose reputation points.
- If you ask a question and you double check to make sure that you've included all of the information necessary to answer the question, you're likely to gain reputation points.

Assuming that most people administering upvotes and downvotes are doing so according to a common criteria, the system should only encourage good behaviors and discourage bad behaviors. Unfortunately this doesn't always happen, and the system isn't perfect, so sometimes bad behaviors can seem encouraged and good behaviors can seem discouraged, or the signals you're receiving can sometimes be downright confusing; but we do the best we can with what we have and the system largely works.

Now for questions:

> Can someone give me tips on how to make good answers and questions...?

This is just way too broad for me to touch. We've amassed so many good meta questions about asking and answering, as well as a bunch of help center articles on the topic, that I feel it would be a disservice to try and sum them all up in a few paragraphs or less.

> Can someone give me tips on ... how to relieve stress?

That's... kind of missing the point of gamification. Embrace the stress. Double, triple, and quadruple check your posts before posting. Make sure that you've read all of the relevant documentation in the help center, and if you're unsure about an action you're about to perform look it up on meta or ask a question on meta if you can't find anything on the topic. At least on meta downvotes don't cost you reputation points.

Comment: "If you ask a question without including the information that is necessary for us to answer the question, you're likely to lose reputation points." Sometimes I wonder how likely that actually is now.

Comment: @jpmc26 from what I hear, in the android tag you would probably gain reputation points.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes stress and fear can be good things if you are able to handle them, especially if you can use them to help you write better posts.

Stress and fear are a problem if they make you get sick, fall asleep, cause social problems, etc. By the way there are other sites that could be helpful about stress management:

- https://health.stackexchange.com
- https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com

Regarding how to write good answers and questions we have some the following help articles

- [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [How do I write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9):

I think a certain amount of stress and fear is an intentional part of the Stack Exchange experience. Every time you post, you essentially open yourself up to criticism and comment by the entire userbase. That's a daunting thing, especially if you don't feel like you're an expert yet.

But it's also part of what makes the site work, what causes people to put their best foot forward when answering and asking, and what incentivizes them to come back - that rush of excitement when your answer is well received and helps people and you see that with a little bit of rep thrown your way, and that's one of the reasons why people spend their incredibly valuable free time doing what is essentially professional work for free.

So, relieving the stress won't really work. You have to learn to incorporate it into your process of contributing - make sure your content is up to scratch and take improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I will address an implied question: "How do I prevent my questions from being downvoted?"

I reviewed your recent questions and found some common, concrete areas for improvement.

**Prefer simple sentences**

An excerpt from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117574/nothing-appears-when-drag-and-dropping-anything-from-the-palette-in-android-stud):

> One day I started a Basic Layout program with a feature in Android Studio but once I was complete with the setup the "Hello World!" Text and other items from the palette that I dragged-and-dropped didn't show up on the design and in the blueprint. I made the items visible and I even changed the settings and the code of the program but nothing worked.

I see two and a half full lines of text before the first structural punctuation mark. I struggle to parse all of that in a single pass, and I am a native English speaker; many contributors are not. Tools like [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/1) may help  identify run-on sentences before you post.

**Omit needless words**

Per Strunk and White's *Elements of Style*, "vigorous writing is concise." If you can cut part of sentence and retain the original meaning, then that excess is stealing attention from your issue and making it harder for others to read.

Here is a revised version of the quoted paragraph. There is room for further improvement; my edits were only to omit needles words and break up rambling sentences:

> I started a Basic Layout program with a feature in Android Studio. Once I was complete with the setup, the "Hello World!" Text and other items from the palette that I dragged-and-dropped didn't show up on the design and in the blueprint. I made the items visible, and I changed the settings and the code of the program. Nothing worked.

**Show your work**

I don't know enough about Android to provide a detailed critique of your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140599/android-emulator-wont-start-up-when-testing-android-studio-program), but there are aspects of it that make me suspicious. This seems like a problem that would be very common to have. There are [40 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=emulator+won%27t+start+%5Bandroid-studio%5D) for "emulator won't start [android-studio]." Is it really the case that none of these apply to your situation? Have you attempted any of the solutions in those questions? Have you attempted any solutions? (Have you tried turning it off and on again?)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476766/android-emulator-wont-start-from-android-studio-on-windows-10) question for a good example of the asker demonstrating their attempts to solve the problem before asking.

---

On a positive note, I do see significant improvement in your September questions over your early ones. The questions are well-structured, there are fewer useless details, and in general it seems you are making an effort to make it easy to read and answer your questions.